# View diff of changes since last rebase after pulling

Tags: git

I have git pull configured to do a rebase. In addition, I've also enabled `rebase.stat` in my config so that I can see what new changes are being introduced in my branch when I rebase it:

```
$ git pull
 .../zMovie/Source/FormManagers/FrmHome.cpp         | 105 +++++++++------------
 .../zMovie/Source/FormManagers/FrmTheater.cpp      |  26 ++++-
 .../zMovie/Source/FormManagers/FrmTheater.h        |   2 +-
 3 files changed, 72 insertions(+), 61 deletions(-)
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

The problem I have here is that Git seems to shorten the path to the updated files, so I can't simply copy/paste them to see individual diffs of them. Often times I like to compare what was changed in a file brought into my branch:

```
$ git diff master~ master -- .../zMovie/Source/FormManagers/FrmHome.cpp
```

However, the above won't work since I don't have the complete path to the file (relative to the repo root of course). It's omitted the top level of the path to keep it short enough for the column it is displayed in.

I'd also be happy if the output from the `git pull` displayed the revision range from `master` from which the new changes come from, that way I can just `git diff` on that range, but I don't get that in the output.

Is there a way to improve my workflow for this? I really just want to view a diff (preferably with `difftool`) of the new changes introduced since the last rebase on my `master` branch.

Comment: I tend to be more old-school-manually-do-everything about this, using `git fetch` instead of pull (with or without rebase), but what comes to mind here is using the reflogs.  I'm not sure what you want to see: is it "what they did", what happened from old origin/master to new origin/master; or is it "whatever-they-did, what changed in my rebased tip" (diff old master vs new master), or maybe something else?

Comment: @torek I want to look at the diff between my OLD rebased tip and my NEW (current) rebased tip.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, as the previous tip commit (what your `master` pointed to before the pull) isn't what I'd call "rebased", or at least not as part of the `git pull --rebase` step; only the new (post-`pull`) one is.  But (and again I have not tried this myself) it's likely name-able, post `git pull --rebase`, as `master@{1}` or similar.  `git reflog show master` will tell you what `@{...}` suffix to use.

Comment: @torek I'm not sure what you mean. What I'm basically asking for is: `git diff \`git merge-base master topic1\` master`. However, I want to be able to do this *after* performing a rebase. Which means I'd need some way of referring to the last point my branch was at before the rebase.

Comment: OK ... and, the commit your branch pointed to pre-rebase is in the reflog for the branch.  So, use `git merge-base master@{1} ...` to find the starting point.  See the git-pull script, which simply runs `git rebase ...` at the end, and `git rebase` updates the ref while leaving the previous tip in the reflog.

Comment: @torek I had a chance to test using the `master@{n}` syntax and it works wonderfully. Please post an answer and I will give you a green checkmark :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on comments, let's note:

1. The `pull` script is basically the same as<sup>1</sup> `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase`, depending on which one you ask for (in your config setup or with `--rebase`).
2. Using [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax, we can find "the commit some branch name, like `master`, pointed to before the rebase ran" with `master@{1}`.  (The reflog syntax is described in more detail in the [`git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).)

Thus, you can see what the rebase did to your code with `git diff branch@{1} branch` (note: in some shells, not including bash but including csh/tcsh, you have to quote the braces to get this to work: `git diff 'branch@{1}' branch` or `git diff branch@\{1} branch`, for instance).

(You can get even fancier: [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax can be used pretty much anywhere, so you can use these as arguments to [`git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html), for instance.)

---

Long illustration follows, feel free to skip.

Before fetch-and-rebase, you might have something like this:

```
        o--o--o   <-- master
       /
c--c--c           <-- origin/master
```

The `c` commit-nodes are "common" (shared between you and everyone else), while the `o` commit-nodes are "ours" (or "original"), i.e., your own work, not yet shared with anyone.

When you `fetch` this brings in new work, let's call them `C` for also-common-but-new:

```
        o--o--o   <-- master
       /
c--c--c--C--C     <-- origin/master
```

(see footnote 1 for minor caveat).  At this point nothing has happened to `master`, but then the pull does a `git rebase`, as you instructed it to.  This copies your `o` commits to new, somewhat different commits (they now include stuff that was changed in the `C` commits):

```
        o--o--o   <-- master@{1}
       /
c--c--c--C--C     <-- origin/master
             \
              *--*--*   <-- master
```

The three original commits (`o`) are still in there.  Normally they're invisible: I label them "abandoned" in similar drawings in other StackOverflow answers, as they have no branch-name pointing to them.  The reflog, though, keeps "previous references" alive for a while (default = 30 days), and the `@{1}` or `@{yesterday}` or other similar syntax can be used to dig them out.

So `git diff master@{1} master` compares the last `o` commit with the last `*` commit, which shows you how "what they did" affects "what you did".

(Note that `origin/master` *also* has a reflog.  If you do a regular `fetch`, so that `origin/master` is updated, you can `git diff origin/master@{1} origin/master` to compare the last `c` commit against the second `C` commit.  If you use `git pull`, however, this needs git 1.8.4 or newer to get `origin/master` updated; see footnote 1.)

---

<sup>1</sup>When you `git pull origin master` this really does run `git fetch origin master`, i.e., it really does invoke `git fetch` directly.  The thing here is that it gives `fetch` *two* arguments: the remote, and a branch name.  In git versions older than 1.8.4, this changes the way `fetch` operates, so that fetch *does not* update `origin/master`.  In 1.8.4 and newer, `fetch` updates the remote-branch `origin/master`, which makes more sense: now that "our git" knows that "their git" has new commits, we really should just update our idea of where `master` is over there.  (That's all a "remote branch" is: a copy, locally, of where "their" branch was, the last time we checked.)

The `fetch` command always writes the fetched-branch information to the file `FETCH_HEAD` in the top level git directory.  It does this no matter how it's invoked.  While `FETCH_HEAD` looks a lot like a regular reference a la `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on, it has some extra information on each line, left there specifically for the `pull` script.

In all cases, after `fetch` brings in new commits and maybe-updates-remote-branches, the `pull` script then extracts the SHA-1 ID of the newest commit from `FETCH_HEAD`.  It supplies this raw SHA-1 ID to either `merge` or `rebase`.

There's one more special case though: when `git pull` is going to rebase, it has some fancy logic for detecting and recovering from a rebase on the remote.  Normally this should not happen (it's not a good idea to retract published/shared commits), but `git pull --rebase` can handle it, while regular `git rebase` needs extra help from the user.  (There is a new feature in git 1.9/2.0 to make this work better.)

I think it's worth looking through `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-pull` (if this is where your `git-core` directory lives: sometimes it's `/usr/libexec` instead, or somewhere else) to see how this works.

Comment: +1 I have documented the new `git fetch` behavior in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20967347/6309.