# git fetch and subsequent merge does not do the same as git pull - Why?

Tags: git, github

most likely I am missing something here.

Why does

```
git fetch origin master
```

with the output

```
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://github.com/groupschoof/PhyloFun
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and a subsequent

```
git merge origin/master
```

give the output

```
Already up-to-date.
```

While

```
git pull origin master
```

does

```
From https://github.com/groupschoof/PhyloFun
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating c6bd22b..234cd22
Fast-forward
 R/geneOntologySQL.R |   77 ++++++++++[rest of line omitted]
 1 file changed, 30 insertions(+), 47 deletions(-)
```

So in short why does a `git pull origin master` trigger the merging of fetched patches, while the combined `git fetch origin master` and subsequent `git merge origin/master` does not?

For enlightenment I will be very grateful!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So in short why does a `git pull origin master` trigger the merging of fetched patches, while the combined `git fetch origin master` and subsequent `git merge origin/master` does not?

Firstly, since git 1.8.4, git fetch will always update `origin/master` in addition of `FETCH_HEAD`: see "[`git fetch`, `FETCH_HEAD` and `origin/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20967347/6309)".
That means a `git merge origin/master` will always return a `Already up-to-date` message.

Secondly, `git pull` is a `git fetch` + a `git merge` on the current *local* branch (not remote tracking branch): it merges on `master`, not `origin/master`.

The (fast-forward) merge seen in the question is the `master` branch being updated.