# Git fetch: origin/master different from FETCH_HEAD

Tags: git, msysgit, git-fetch

I'm using MsysGit. After I do `git fetch origin master`, and run `git diff master origin/master` nothing shows up. But if I run `git diff master FETCH_HEAD` the differences will show up. Haven't changed any settings, how come it's like that?

Note I have the line `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` existing in `.git/config`g

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: My git version is 1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to upgrade the msysgit installation (see [msysgit releases](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases)).

As I mention in "[`git fetch`, `FETCH_HEAD` and `origin/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20967347/6309)", **since git 1.8.4 (August 2013)** `git fetch origin master` will actually update `origin/master`, not just `FETCH_HEAD`.