# git pull --rebase leads to unexpected graph

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am working on a branch, `foo`. I have no unstaged changes, no working changes, perfectly clean state, where `HEAD` == `foo` == `origin/foo` according to my box.

```
$ git status
# On branch foo
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   some_irrelevant_file_here

$ git log --pretty=...
* 456520c 2015-02-13 (HEAD, origin/foo, foo) Commit A
* 23bfcd1 2015-02-11 Commit B
* b0bdd18 2015-02-12 Commit C
```

I am then asked to look at some changes that a colleague pushed, so I do:

```
$ git pull --rebase origin foo
remote: Counting objects: 47, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 36 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (36/36), done.
From ...
 * branch            foo       -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded foo to 43dad88c737762e0f1e84fdcd135155080bdce2a.
```

At this point, my graph looks like:

```
$ git log --pretty=...
* 43dad88 2015-02-13 (HEAD, foo) Commit D
* 40039f9 2015-02-13 Commit E
* 456520c 2015-02-13 (origin/foo) Commit A
* 23bfcd1 2015-02-11 Commit B
* b0bdd18 2015-02-12 Commit C
```

Why does it look like my local `foo` is ahead of `origin/foo`? Neither `D` nor `E` are my commits, I just pulled both of those from `origin` - I'd expect at this point to still have `HEAD` == `foo` == `origin/foo`.

Comment: "according to my box". Your box might be outdated. What happenes if you run `git fetch origin foo` first?

Comment: @jurgemaister the pull --rebase does a fetch implicitly.

Comment: I'd have expected `* (HEAD, foo) commit C
* (origin/foo, origin/HEAD) commit A
* commit B
* commit D`

Comment: @RobertBain I think jurgemaister is referring to the "diff preview" when you checkout a certain branch and it gets compared to the origin _based on the last fetch_. So that information can be misleading sometimes.

Comment: @CodyStott we're looking at the commit history, not the diff preview - we're passed that stage. There's been a `git pull --rebase origin foo`, so effectively a `git fetch origin foo` and a `git rebase origin/foo`. The fetch has already happened.

Comment: @RobertBain I know what `git pull` does. My comment however is based on the fact that the original question mentions the fact that he "knows" that his local is even with the remote _before_ he mentions doing the `git pull`. Just consider the sequence of what he says.

Comment: @CodyStott that doesn't explain the order of the commits. If locally there are no unstaged changes, no working changes and a perfectly clean state where HEAD == foo == origin/foo, then doing a fetch and rebase should replay the commit C on top of remote's HEAD.

Comment: @RobertBain "Neither `A` nor `B` are my commits, I just pulled both of those from `origin`" So what he's saying is that he did a (default?) `git pull` which merges on top of his local `foo`, then he rebases off of `origin/foo` which I'm assuming doesn't have `A` or `B` and you are wondering why `A` and `B` are at the top?

Comment: @CodyStott in my mind that's not what he's saying. I think he's saying he did a `git pull --rebase origin foo`, which is the same as `git fetch origin foo` and a `git rebase origin/foo`. I'd be happy to chat about this further in discussion or perhaps just leave it for others to offer their thoughts.

Comment: @CodyStott I did no `git pull`, just `git pull --rebase origin foo`. Is there anything I can clarify?

Comment: @RobertBain I added more detail into the question, with some SHAs and the output of all my commands and stuff (I ran exactly these commands in order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you had before the `pull --rebase` was:

```
x--x--x (foo, HEAD, origin/foo)
       \
        y--y (actual origin/foo)
```

When you `pull --rebase`, you are asking to replay your local commits on top of `origin/foo`:
`foo` is reset/checked out at `origin/foo` (which is fetched in `FETCH_HEAD`), and since your commits '`x`' are already part of the new updated `FETCH_HEAD`, `foo` is simply fast-forwarded:

```
x--x--x--y--y (foo, HEAD, FETCH_HEAD)
      |
 (origin/foo)
```

The fact that `origin/foo` has *not* changed is typical of a [git older than 1.8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20967347/6309) (found for instance in [Ubuntu Precise 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/git-core), which comes with and old `git-core` 1.7.9.5)

A simple `git fetch` should be enough to update `origin/foo`, and not just `FETCH_HEAD`.

A more recent git (1.8.4+) would have updated both `FETCH_HEAD` and `origin/foo`, making the additional `git fetch` redundant.

---

Note: with Git 2.12 (Q1 2017), this case (pull --rebase) will be a simple fast-forward merge.

See [commit 33b842a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33b842a1e9bf28bcffe953ad9dcdbb0561336314) (29 Jun 2016) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster). 
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2fb11ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fb11ec6c175e8a380d91daccc3bbf9fc5bbea8b), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### `pull`: fast-forward "`pull --rebase=true`"
>
> "`git pull --rebase`" always runs "`git rebase`" after fetching the
>   commit to serve as the new base, **even when the new base is a
>   descendant of the current HEAD**, i.e. we haven't done any work.
>
> In such a case, **we can instead fast-forward to the new base without
>   invoking the rebase process**.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not pushed to the repo that is a normal behavior. How come you can have your local commits before origin? They will always be on top.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it look like my local foo is ahead of origin/foo?

That `foo` is ahead of `remote/foo` is expected, because [rebase plays back your *current* branch on top of the upstream branch](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). You rebased `foo` on top of the `remote/foo`, so `foo` should be ahead of `remote/foo`.

> HEAD == foo == origin/foo according to my box.

As a result, the order of commits is also as expected. The following is how your branching would look *before* a rebase or merge where `A` is the actual state of the remote and `C` is your stale representation of the remote.

```
D <------C (HEAD, foo, remote/foo) <------B <------A (remote/foo)
```

You're doing the equivalent of a "fast-forward" rebase. I.e. it doesn't do anything to the commits; there is nothing to play back onto `remote/foo`! The result should only change ref locations:

```
D <------C <------B <------A (HEAD, foo, remote/foo)
```

> Why does it look like my local foo is ahead of origin/foo?

That's the question I haven't been able to answer. After the rebase, I would expect again that `HEAD` == `foo` == `remote/foo` but it doesn't.  Why after the rebase of `foo` onto `remote/foo` does the latter appear to be behind?

Comment: Yes, that is both what I would expect, and my question.

Comment: @Barry Where's Linus when we need him?

Comment: It seems so bizarre that I'm inclined to think that something's gone wrong and somehow the local repo is corrupted. I have no doubt that the purpose of the question is to clear up any possible misunderstanding but in light of any decent answer, I'd be tempted to diff HEAD HEAD~1 into a file, patch, push and hope it doesn't happen again.

Comment: @RobertBain no, it is just an old git (pre 1.8.4): See [my answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29081368/6309).

Comment: @VonC, what a subtle one, good catch. Can I assume you've run into the same problem before?

Comment: @RobertBain yes, indeed. Plus I had quite a few questions here on Stack Overflow from users on Ubuntu 12.04 (the previous LTS version), using the default old git 1.7.9.5. And I documented that change before (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20967347/6309).