# git alias to pull --rebase current branch

Tags: git, git-alias

I am working on a branch called `foo` and I want to rebase my branch against `origin/foo`. In modern versions of git I could run

```
$ git pull --rebase origin foo
```

That's a lot of typing for a common operation. Additionally, because I have an old version of git (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29081368/2069064)), I also need to run a fetch first so that my local graph doesn't seem confusing:

```
$ git fetch && git pull --rebase origin foo
```

How can I write that as a git alias?

Comment: Does your branch not have an upstream set? I just use `git pull --rebase` and it uses the upstream branch. I don't think I have anything custom in place.

Comment: @ChrisHayes How do you check if it does?

Comment: A quick gander at [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/175052/how-to-tell-which-local-branch-is-tracking-which-remote-branch-in-git) suggests `git branch -vv` should do the trick. For me, it shows `* master 9aa5d6a [origin/master] <latest-commit-message>`, which correctly shows origin/master as my upstream. You can also use `git remote show origin` for more verbose output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

outputs the short name of the current branch, if any (or `HEAD`, if the HEAD is detached). Therefore, you can use it inside a command substitution in your alias definition:

```
git config --global alias.<name> '!git fetch && git pull --rebase origin $(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)'
```

where `<name>` stands for your alias's name.

Comment: Better option is to use `git fetch && git rebase @{u}`. Or just [`git-up`](https://github.com/aanand/git-up).

Comment: @hauleth Perhaps, but that's under the assumption that the current branch has an upstream, which may not be the case. I guess it's up to you. Also, the OP uses an old version of Git, and I'm not sure when `@{u}` was introduced.