# How do I find the version of Git repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, terminal

I cloned a git repository yesterday and am using it in Ubuntu. I need to find the version of that cloned repository I am using. What is the command for that?

Comment: What do you mean by version? Git has no concept of versions.

Comment: From the context, we can read that he means "version  =commit". He is trying to know if he is up to date with the latest commit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the more common `git log -1` or the less used `git rev-parse HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

If you have not pushed yes, you can check the version of [`origin/master`, or of `FETCH_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15032159/6309) (see [`FETCH_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237511/6309))

```
cd /path/to/your/local/cloned/repo
git rev-parse origin/master
git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD
```

That will give you the commit ID (SHA1) of what was last fetched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I get this output:
user@lappy:~$ git rev-parse 

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

user@lappy:~$ 

user@lappy:~$ 17

17: command not found

user@lappy:~$ 191

191: command not found

user@lappy:~$ 

user@lappy:~$     37

37: command not found

user@lappy:~$ 

user@lappy:~$ mjkaufer/Messer

bash: mjkaufer/Messer: No such file or directory

user@lappy:~$ 

As we see, it says its not a git repo at all. But it is!
The repo: https://github.com/mjkaufer/Messer/issues/63

Comment: @shanmuganathan Yes, I have edited the answer: you need to execute that command in the root folder of your cloned repository. And `~` (`$HOME`) should not be a Git repository. One of your subfolder should be a Git repository: `git clone /url/to/repo` would create a `repo` subfolder.

Comment: "git clone /url/to/repo would create a repo subfolder." I already did that while cloning the repo

Comment: @shanmuganathan Do you remember in which folder (presumably your home directory) you were when you typed `git clone /url/to/remote/repo`? That command will have created a subfolder, by default named after the repository name. Do a `cd repo` and you would be in that repository folder.

Comment: @shanmuganathan " I already did that while cloning the repo": yes, now you need to go in that repository, with a `cd name-of-your-repository`

Comment: I got it. Thanks.