# Egit understanding FETCH_HEAD behavior

Tags: eclipse, egit

1. Created a repo on Github (initialized with a readme).
2. Cloned it with Egit.
3. Saw that FETCH_HEAD and HEAD were checked out.
4. Went to Github and made a change to the readme.
5. Fetched the change.
6. Saw that HEAD was checked out, FETCH_HEAD wasn't. But FETCH_HEAD did have the readme update. The tracking branch for origin/master also had the update.
7. Merged the tracking branch for origin/master into my local master.
8. Saw that both FETCH_HEAD and HEAD were checked out again.

[image: FETCH_HEAD]

According to this post:  [What does FETCH_HEAD in Git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean)

> FETCH_HEAD is a short-lived ref, to keep track of what has just been
>   fetched from the remote repository.

Why isn't FETCH_HEAD checked out right after fetching? Why did it only become checked out after I merged the origin's tracking branch into my local master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't `FETCH_HEAD` checked out right after fetching? Why did it only become checked out after I merged the origin's tracking branch into my local master?

`FETCH_HEAD` in itself doesn't reference any branch: it only remember the last fetched SHA1.
As it doesn't reference a branch, it isn't really checked out (and shouldn't be checked out), or you would end up with a **[detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)**.

However, merging the tracking branch to the `master` branch will update `HEAD` (which points to the updated master): that branch is checked out.
If the merge is a ["**fast-forward**" one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684404/6309), the checked-out branch `HEAD` and **`FETCH-HEAD` would reference the same SHA1, giving the impression that `FETCH_HEAD` is "checked out"** (it isn't really)

---

In other words, in the following picture:

[image: checked out in Egit]

`FETCH_HEAD` has the "checked-out" tick **only because it reference the same SHA1 than the current checked-out branch `HEAD` (here `master`)**.

That means that, if you do **a new commit**:

- `FETCH_HEAD` wouldn't have the checked-out tick anymore (it would still reference the last fetched SHA1). That is why I say it isn't "really" checked-out (in the sense of "it wouldn't *stay* checked-out after a new commit, since it is a *fixed* reference to a particular SHA1)
- `HEAD` and the `master` branch would reference a new SHA1, and would keep the checked-out tick.

But if you were to check out directly the `FETCH_HEAD` SHA1 (before merging it to `master`: [the Egit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#.22Detached.22_HEAD) mentions you can do that if the reference isn't already checked-out), then:

- `FETCH_HEAD` would still be "checked-out"
- same for `HEAD`
- but `master` (or any other branch) would **not be checked-out anymore**: this is a [DETACHED HEAD situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)

If you were to make a *new* commit on top of a checked-out `FETCH_HEAD`:

- `FETCH_HEAD` would no longer be checked-out (since it remains fixed on the last fetched SHA1)
- HEAD would point to the new commit checked-out.
- no branch would be "checked-out": detached HEAD.

You would need to open that checked-out commit done on top of `FETCH_HEAD`, and create a branch from there:

[image: create a branch]

(from the article "[Git Lesson: Be mindful of a detached head](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/29/life-lesson-be-mindful-of-a-detached-head/)")

---

In conclusion:

Each time you see a "checked-out tick" on the `FETCH_HEAD` reference, it is because **it references the same SHA1 than the ref currently checked out** (either a commit, or a branch).
It is *not* because `FETCH_HEAD` itself is checked out: it you do a new commit on top of it, it won't be checked out anymore.

Comment: You say: "As it doesn't reference a branch, it sin"t checked out..." Well it certainly shows as being checked out right after cloning and right after merging. (I added an image to the original question.) Sounds like this might be a Egit issue.

Comment: @mike you need to see the situation from the perspective of "what happens when I make a *new* commit on top of that "checked-out" `FETCH_HEAD`?": I have updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: @mike I have added a small conclusion which summarizes why `FETCH_HEAD` *appears* checked out, but isn't really.