# What's the difference between "git fetch <url>" and "git add remote upstream <url>" followed by "git fetch upstream"?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I was trying to pull changes from upstream into my fork. I tried `git fetch https://github.com/someuser/someproject`, but it stubbornly refused to do anything. It just said something totally cryptic and did nothing, namely:

```
From https://github.com/someuser/someproject
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

But the moment I added the URL as a named remote, things changed:

```
> git remote add upstream https://github.com/someuser/someproject.git
> git fetch upstream
remote: Counting objects: 340, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (268/268), done.
remote: Total 340 (delta 145), reused 18 (delta 16), pack-reused 44
... etc ...
```

So what's the difference? Why did it do nothing when I specified a remote without adding it first? And what exactly was it telling me when I tried to fetch from the URL?

Comment: Are you sure it did not work? Did you try to checkout or merge magic reference called `FETCH_HEAD` ?

Comment: @RetoAebersold Yes. Tried it again: clean clone, then the fetch (instantaneous), then I tried to `git checkout <hash>` that's there in upstream - "did not match". Then I did the "remote add", "fetch upstream" (this time takes a while), then `checkout <hash>` again - got a detached head as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fetch with a URL, you also have to specify the [`<refspec>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt) you want to fetch, i.e. the branch or tag, otherwise it will just fetch the default `HEAD` of the remote URL as `FETCH_HEAD`, which is probably not what you want.

The syntax is an optional `+` followed by `<src>:<dst>`. If you omit `<dst>`, `FETCH_HEAD` will be used.

So for example:

```
git fetch https://github.com/someuser/someproject refs/heads/master:upstream/master
```

which will create the `upstream/master` remote branch locally.

[More advanced options are available.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this, so I've used Google and [the man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) to help piece together what's going on.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean) should demystify the `FETCH_HEAD` aspect of things. It's not really possible for me to tell what the state of your repo is from reading your question, but presumably your `FETCH_HEAD` points to the latest commit in the `HEAD` in the remote repo, whatever that might happen to be. You probably already had those commits on your system, and so all git did was update `FETCH_HEAD`. You probably want to provide a branch instead.

When you add a remote, you get additional functionality, like a default branch and remote-tracking branches. I believe your second command as acting differently because `git` is employing some implicit logic to do what's typically wanted. Fetching directly from a URL is more of an advanced move, and you get fewer assumptions for that reason.

Moral of the story, if you want things to Just Work, add a remote. Otherwise, be prepared to grapple with more of the underlying details.