# What will happen if I delete HEAD and FETCH_HEAD under .git

Tags: git, version-control, metadata

What will happen if I delete the `HEAD` and `FETCH_HEAD` under directory .git?

I did delete these files and and made some changes to `README.txt` tried pulling and pushing(without creating any branches). It worked fine.
Will it create problems if I do more serious things? like rebasing and resetting?

How Git keeps tracks of which current branch I am working on? I thought `HEAD` and `FETCH_HEAD` supposed to signify those things. What are all the files and directories under `.git` that I can delete and still the git will continue to work?

In other words, what are the bare essential things under `.git` necesssary for git to work locally and with remote flawlessly?

```
$ pwd
/home/arulmozhi/_/remote-repo/.git
$ rm HEAD
$ cd ..
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.

$ cat README.md
this stuff is from dummy branch
First file in repo which is to be synced across multiple remotes - gitlab and github

$ emacs -nw README.md

$ git commit -am "what happens when we rename/delete .git/HEAD"
[master 34d647b] what happens when we rename/delete .git/HEAD
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git push
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 401 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@gitlab.com:remote-repo/remote-repo.git
   fa76250..34d647b  master -> master

$ uname -arn
Linux koparakesari 3.19.0-31-generic #36~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 10:21:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ls -1 .git
branches
COMMIT_EDITMSG
config
description
hooks
index
info
logs
objects
packed-refs
refs
```

Comment: If you want everything to work flawlessly, assume that you should not touch `.git` yourself. Any answer that fully documents the results of any manual changes is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That means you must have another .git folder in `/home/arulmozhi/_` or `/home/arulmozhi`: the folder `remote-repo` could be a nested git repo.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted **[`HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309)**, and it did "create problem" (git 2.6.4):

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test>rm .git\HEAD

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\test>git st
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I had to restore the content of HEAD (`ref: refs/heads/master`) in order for the repo to be recognized again.

**[`FETCH_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237511/6309)**, on the other hand, is regenerated at the next `git fetch`.

Comment: @vanangamudi If you delete `HEAD` you no longer have a git repository (by definition).  Whether that's a problem or not, I suppose, is left up to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /test/.git/
$ git status
On branch master
...
$ rm .git/HEAD 
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

So, apparently there has been something different in your test case that cannot be reproduced.