# Flutter : /opt/..../FETCH_HEAD exists in filesystem Arch

Tags: flutter, dart, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

While I'm updating and installing some packages on Arch Linux:

```bash
sudo pacman -Syu && sudo pacman -S --needed \
webkit2gtk \
base-devel \
curl \
wget \...
```

I got following error:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
flutter: /opt/flutter/.git/FETCH_HEAD exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Comment: I solved it by just remove and change permission of `/opt/flutter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed with `sudo rm -rf /opt/flutter/.git/FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: If anything went wrong so for this i have create a backup file then i did this... Well This Method Works...

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD` is safe to delete :-) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34397566/2310634 or https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Can-I-delete-tidy-up-old-FETCH-HEAD-files/qaq-p/775591#M38820

Manjaro user here with the same exact problem.  It must have been from a recent AUR update.