# How to download one specific gerrit change set in jenkins git plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit-trigger

Normally we use [gerrit trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) in jenkins to download the gerrit changeset.

But in some case, we want to download the specific changesets directly.

For example [openstack Change #503032](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/503032/)

```
git pull git://git.openstack.org/openstack/tripleo-quickstart-extras refs/changes/32/503032/2
```

And set the `Refspec` to `refs/changes/32/503032/2` in git repo like

[image]

And enable the `Honor refspec on initial clone` in Additional behaviours like

[image]

But I got error in console log

```
Fetching upstream changes from git://git.openstack.org/openstack/tripleo-quickstart-extras
 > git fetch --tags --progress git://git.openstack.org/openstack/tripleo-quickstart-extras refs/changes/32/503032/2 --depth=1
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

Any suggestion, we don't want to use the extra command in shell build step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set "Branch" to `FETCH_HEAD` and the specified refspec will be checked out.

`FETCH_HEAD` is a temporary ref pointing to the latest fetched refspec, eg. branch, commit. See this question for more information: [What does FETCH_HEAD in Git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Refspec` to `refs/changes/32/503032/2:refs/changes/32/503032/2`
and `Branches to build` to `refs/changes/32/503032/2`

Alternetively, you can push the change to another branch and point to that branch from `Branches to build`.