# What does git fetch followed by checkout FETCH_HEAD do?

Tags: git

What does the following command do:

```
git fetch <remote> <branch> && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

I have only one local branch (`master`) and I execute the above command. What changes to my local repository should I expect and how can I verify (see) them?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably aware of what the first part of your command will do.  `git fetch <remote> <some_branch>` will update the local tracking branch of the branch you specify.  But this will not alter the actual local corresponding `some_branch` on your machine.

When you do a `git fetch`, Git has a special ref called `FETCH_HEAD` which points to the branch which was just fetched.  In this case, it would point to `remote/some_branch`, since this is the branch which was just fetched.  By doing

```
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

you would be checking out `origin/some_branch` in a detached HEAD state.  This may or not may not be what you intend, but in any case, your compound command would not actually update the local `some_branch`.  To do that, you would need an additional `git merge` step, or to just do a `git pull` from `some_branch`.

Comment: Few points: (1) I do not think that I have a "local tracking branch". If I execute "git branch -r" (before and after the fetch) I do not see the branch that I am fetching. (2) I am not sure I understood your explanation of the "git checkout FETCH_HEAD" command. Do you mean that by executing this command I just go to a "local copy" of the remote branch that i have just fetched?

Comment: Um...you certainly have a local tracking branch, or else the fetch/pull would not be possible.  Type `git branch -a` and you will see the local and tracking branches.  If you `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` then you would checkout the local tracking branch in the detached HEAD state.  If some of the terms I am using are unfamiliar to you, then research them because they come up often in Git lingo.