# git FETCH_HEAD short lived reference

Tags: git

1. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237511/2844702) that git FETCH_HEAD is a short lived reference . What is the life of git FETCH_HEAD reference ?
2. When I do `git fetch origin` , in such cases many remote tracking branch are updated. Where will FETCH_HEAD point to ?

Comment: That's _two_ questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's not really a true reference at all; a reference is a pointer to a single commit (or, in the case of `HEAD`, a branch name).  `FETCH_HEAD` instead is git metadata about the branches that were last fetched.  It lives until it's rewritten by *another* fetch
2. It's not a true reference, and contains *all* the information about the remote tracking information that was fetched.

When you run `git merge FETCH_HEAD` (or do so implicitly, by running `git pull`), git treats this specially, and not like a normal reference.  Instead, the `FETCH_HEAD` file will be consulted, and git will look for a branch that does not have the special token `not-for-merge` given to it.  That branch will be the one used for the merge.  (Git determined this branch based on the remote tracking branch corresponding to your `git fetch` invocation or the branch that you were on when you ran it.)

Note that in `FETCH_HEAD`, the details about the remote branch are also included, which allows git to create a message for the merge commit that details *where* that branch came from.  (eg, "`Merge of branch 'master' of https://my.visualstudio.com/my/repository`").

`FETCH_HEAD`, like much of the git repository metadata, is just a text file; reading it to see how it changes after each fetch is incredibly illuminating.  (You can see, for example, that the answer that you link to is terribly incorrect, and that `FETCH_HEAD` does *not* contain a single branch's information, it contains *all* the branches on the remote.)

Comment: "in the case of  `HEAD`, a branch name". What about detached-HEAD state?

Comment: as far as I read , `git pull origin master` does a fetch and then merge. While doing merge , it does `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. If FETCH_HEAD contains metadata abt all branches fetched , then why does git pull uses FETCH_HEAD to do merges ? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's exactly what `git pull` does.  `FETCH_HEAD` includes tab-separated fields, and one of those is an indication about which of the branches fetched should be merged.  (The branch to be merged has a field with the value `for-merge`, in all other branches it will be empty.)  `git merge FETCH_HEAD` resolves this information specially and does not treat `FETCH_HEAD` as if it were a normal branch.

Comment: Pardon me, I had that backwards.  All but one will be labeled `not-for-merge`.

Comment: So, we cannot call git fetch_head reference. what is this entity called ? Shud I just say fetch_head is a file in my git directory ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose if you want a description, that's a correct one.

Comment: Is there any ordering implied by the `FETCH_HEAD` entries? Like, is the ref entry for the current branch I'm on always listed first?

Answer (score 2):

As it says in [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrefnamegtemegemmasterememheadsmasterememrefsheadsmasterem),

> FETCH_HEAD records the branch which you fetched from a remote
>   repository with your last git fetch invocation.

`FETCH_HEAD` is created by the first `git fetch` and will be updated by `git fetch`. By `git fetch`, it also means `git pull` because `git pull` can be `git fetch + git merge` or `git fetch + git rebase`.

For `git fetch origin foo`, undoubtedly `FETCH_HEAD` points to the tip of `foo`. `foo` is a valid ref that can be fetched from the remote repository. In some rare cases, `foo` can be the hash of a specific object (commit, tree, blob or tag) if `uploadpack.allowTipSHA1InWant` is set `true` in the remote repository, and then `FETCH_HEAD` will point to the object.

It becomes complicated when it comes to `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`. What will `FETCH_HEAD` be updated to? There are many cases. For example, the local repository is in detached HEAD, on a specific branch that has an upstream, on a branch that doesn't have an upstream, or in some other cases. If not digging that deep, we can know the result from the output of `git fetch`. Here is a sample,

```
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
From D:/hello
   ca2d63e..38d365c  ost        -> origin/ost
 * [new branch]      a          -> origin/a
   8fe4b12..db5a0d9  aaa        -> origin/aaa
   36ca690..e00229b  haha       -> origin/haha
   c96b459..5ab6097  master     -> origin/master
   283a081..004375e  mist       -> origin/mist
```

We can see the output says which refs are updated by `git fetch`. `FETCH_HEAD` always points to the first ref's tip. In this sample, `FETCH_HEAD` is `origin/ost`'s tip, `38d365c`. It's also true when fetching only one ref or one object.

If a `git fetch` process fails, `FETCH_HEAD` will become an unknown revision. The file `.git/FETCH_HEAD` still exists and it's just empty.

Comment: How does git decide that FETCH_HEAD should point to `origin/ost` as in the example  ? Is not it dangerous if some one does `git pull origin` ? As we never know what might get merged ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin When no specific ref is given, Git just infers from some facts. In my sample, the local repo is right on the branch `ost` which has `origin/ost` as its tracking branch, so it knows the upstream should be updated and merged and therefore `FETCH_HEAD` points to `origin/ost`. If it was in detached HEAD or another branch that doesn't have an upstream, `FETCH_HEAD` would point to `origin/a` because it would be the first in the alphabet order, and the following `git merge` or `git rebase` would just fail to avoid getting dangerous.