# Why git fetch does not create local branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

From what I understand, whenever you run `git fetch` remote objects are downloaded locally and a lightweight pointer  named `FETCH_HEAD` to the `HEAD` commit of the remote branch is created.

Since a branch is simply a pointer, how is this different from creating a local branch? What design considerations support the case for not creating a local branch whenever using `git fetch`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070496/1256452 (different question, but similar idea)

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Article covers basics. FETCH_HEAD is not even mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this entry [What does FETCH_HEAD in Git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean) .

> Since a branch is simply a pointer, how is this different from creating a local branch? What design considerations support the case for not creating a local branch whenever using git fetch?

Because `git fetch` is meant to repatriate the state of **known** remote branches and associated missing objects. This is different from having an homolog local branch that, in this case, would probably be configured to track its remote homolog.

Branches are very often configured to automatically create that local branches, indeed, but only once you check them out first with `git checkout`.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` **actually can** create *some* new branches, locally, but not *yours*. For each new branch it creates a *remote-tracking branch*, an image of the remote state, with which you can't interact like with *your* local branches, the ones listed on `git branch`.

If some new branches have been created on your remote since last time you fetched, git will get their new references, with all needed ancestry.

Example :

**On your local repo**

```
A---B---C---D <<< master, origin/master
```

**On the remote "origin", where work has been done** (a new branch, and `master` has advanced)

```
A---B---C---D---G <<< master
             \
              \
               E---F <<< new-feature
```

If you fetch at this point, you'll get a new reference `new-feature` (which you can verify with `git branch -r`), and `origin/master` will be updated to point to G, but **not** `master`, which will still be unchanged.

```
               G <<< origin/master
              /
             /
A---B---C---D <<< master
             \
              \
               E---F <<< origin/new-feature
```

And then it also allows you to inspect these new changes *before* deciding whether and how to integrate them to your local work.

Comment: I agree that whenever you are fetching from a remote this is the case. You can check "your" branches and *remote-tracking* branches with git branch -a. However when you fetch from a repo somewhere in the internet that is not one of your remotes the only new reference created is FETCH_HEAD. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I was working with a repository now, and every time I fetched a new remote branch, the command did not create the local one. Checking the `.git/config` file and comparing it with other repositories, I could see that the fetch info was different:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@MYREPOURL.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Once I changed it to the following value, it started working:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```