# List all branches with `git branch -a` does not show recently fetched branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-fetch

I have this history in the console:

```
Resolving deltas: 100% (58156/58156), completed with 1585 local objects.
From bitbucket.org:interos/datavana
 * branch                datavana.dev.py.3.7.3 -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git checkout datavana.dev.py.3.7.3
error: pathspec 'datavana.dev.py.3.7.3' did not match any file(s) known to git

$ git branch
* alex/dockerize
  master

$ git branch -a
* alex/dockerize
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I noticed a problem when I tried running:

```
git checkout datavana.dev.py.3.7.3
```

because as you can see that didn't work, and this branch is also not listed using `git branch -a`, anybody know why I can't checkout this branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look the top of your question, you see:

```
* branch                datavana.dev.py.3.7.3 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

This means that the remote reference `datavana.dev.py.3.7.3` has been stored locally in `FETCH_HEAD`.  It did **not** create a local branch with the same name.

You can **create** a local branch named `datavana.dev.py.3.7.3` by running:

```
git checkout -b datavana.dev.py.3.7.3 FETCH_HEAD
```

---

You probably ran `git fetch <remote> datavana.dev.py.3.7.3`, in which case what you see is the expected behavior.  From the `git-fetch` man page:

> The names of refs that are fetched, together with the object names they point at, are written to .git/FETCH_HEAD. This information may be used by scripts or other git commands, such as git-pull(1).

You would normally check out a remote branch using `git checkout`.

Comment: yeah but why did it do the FETCH_HEAD thing, never seen that before?

Comment: Like I said, you didn't tell us what command you typed that resulted in that output. If you'd care to add that to your question, maybe we can figure out what happened.

Comment: yeah I just ran `git fetch` tmk

Answer (score 0):

> why did it do the `FETCH_HEAD` thing, never seen that before?
> I just ran `git fetch`

Then double-check your `git config remote.origin.fetch` setting:
A [default refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) should have created the local branch for you on fetch:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

But if you have a different refspec, then the remote branch is fetched, and its reference is [stored in FETCH_HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45543739/6309)

A `git fetch datavana.dev.py.3.7.3:datavana.dev.py.3.7.3` would also have created the branch locally.