# How should I read the message a git fetch returns?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I just did

```
get fetch origin feature/8067
```

and below it I got 3 columns:

```
 * branch                feature/8067 -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]          feature/8067 -> origin/feature/8067
```

Trying to process this...reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean) I just learned that `FETCH_HEAD` basically means the tip of where I last did a `fetch`. The file will contain a commit.

Does that `[new branch]` refer to the **new** branch created under my `refs/remote`?

I'm not sure if my reading of the following is correct: `feature/8067 -> origin/feature/8067`

Is the 2nd column the `<nameOfBranchOnRemoteRepo>` while the 3rd column is `<repoName/nameOfBranchOnRemoteRepo>` and it says my fetched remote branch in the refs is pointing to that in the remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch output is confusing even to an old hand.  Here's how I decode them:

> ```
>  * branch                feature/8067 -> FETCH_HEAD
>  * [new branch]          feature/8067 -> origin/feature/8067
> ```

Work each line from right to left:

- The first line ends with `FETCH_HEAD`, which means that the reference was deposited into `FETCH_HEAD`.  See the note about `FETCH_HEAD` below.  The arrow is hardcoded (always appears and you can just sort of ignore it); the name `feature/8067` is the name of the reference on the remote; and `* branch` tells you that it was really `refs/heads/feature/8067` on the remote, i.e., was a branch.  Because this was deposited into `FETCH_HEAD` there's no additional information available.
- The second line ends with `origin/feature/8067`.  Your remote-tracking name<sup>1</sup> `origin/feature/8067` (full name `refs/remotes/origin/feature/8067`) has been created or updated.  As before, we have the arrow and the same name.  Then we have `* [new branch]`: this tells us that `origin/feature/8067` did not exist before, and that `feature/8067` was—as we already know—a branch name on the remote.

Here's what I get updating a Git repository for Git:

> ```
>    ab15ad1a3b..aa25c82427  master      -> origin/master
>    ef7435264c..5a294203ad  next        -> origin/next
>  + f98c0007ae...e49ac33073 pu          -> origin/pu  (forced update)
>    0f4b6a451a..ff8db353a4  todo        -> origin/todo
>  * [new tag]               v2.22.0-rc1 -> v2.22.0-rc1
> ```

Again we can work right to left:

- My `origin/master` got created-or-updated, from their `master`.  The value of my `origin/master` *was* `ab15ad1a3b` but is now `aa25c82427`.  Since there was a value, it's been updated, not created.
- My `origin/next` has been created-or-updated, with everything else basically the same as above (modulo the obvious differences).
- My `origin/pu` has been updated by force, i.e., this is not a fast-forward and some commits have been *deleted*.  The source was their `pu` branch and my `origin/pu` used to be `f98c0007ae` but is now `ff8db353a4`.  The fact that there are three dots between the two hash IDs—the other lines have only two dots—means that the update was forced, hence not a fast-forward.  The plus sign at the very front means that the update was forced.  (Clearly, it's pretty important that the update was forced: I have *three* announcements to that effect!)
- My `origin/todo` has been created-or-updated, and by the time we get to the left side, it's obviously an update.
- My `v2.22.0-rc1` has been created-or-updated, from their `v2.22.0-rc1`; this is a new tag.

Any time you have a new name (branch, tag, or any other reference), it's by definition a regular non-forced creation and there's no `old..new` hash available, so the left edge will read `* [new whatever]`.

`FETCH_HEAD` is special: *all* updates get written to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, usually wiping out whatever was in it before (but with `-a` or `--append`, `git fetch` will append instead).  Each fetched reference results in one line appearing in `FETCH_HEAD`, giving:

- the hash ID
- an optional `not-for-merge` string
- the type and name of the reference and its source:

  ```
  $ cat .git/FETCH_HEAD
  aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6        branch 'master' of git://...
  [snipped for length]
  ```

The one line that is *not* marked `not-for-merge` is suitable for the `git pull` script<sup>2</sup> to fish out and pass that hash ID to `git merge` or `git rebase`.

---

<sup>1</sup>A *remote-tracking name*, which most of Git calls a *remote-tracking branch*, is a *reference* in your repository whose full name starts with `refs/remotes/` and goes on to include the name of the remote, in this case `origin`, and another slash, and then normally holds the rest of the *branch* name as seen on that remote.

A *reference* is just the generalized name for things that are branches, tags, remote-tracking names, `refs/stash`, and so on: a string-format name, generally starting with `refs/`, that remembers one hash ID.  For a branch, the one hash ID the name remembers is the commit that Git should consider to be the *tip* of that branch.  For a tag, the one hash ID the name remembers is either the hash ID of the commit, or the hash ID of an *annotated tag object* that contains additional information (perhaps including a signing key), plus the hash ID of the tagged object (typically a commit though any tag can point to any one of Git's internal object types).

Git builds remote-tracking names through a *refspec*.  You can supply a refspec when you run `git fetch`.  If you do not supply a refspec, but do supply a remote *name* like `origin`, Git fishes the correct refspec from your configuration:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

A standard configuration for `origin` always has this exact default refspec, but there are some useful nonstandard configurations, such as the one created by `git clone --single-branch`.  You can also make your own totally bizarre refspecs, though depending on how twisted you get, some combinations will result in a non-functioning `git fetch`.

<sup>2</sup>Well, back when when `git pull` was a script, anyway.  It's been re-coded in C for speed on Windows.

Comment: WOW. Super thanks. This is too much to digest all at once while at work. To fully process your answer, there's a lot I need to look into. I'll get back to you soon

Comment: _`* branch` tells you that it was really `refs/heads/feature/8067` on the remote, i.e., was a branch_ other than `* branch` & `* [new branch]` what kind of indicator exists?

Comment: _Here's what I get updating a Git repository for Git:_ you must just doing `git fetch origin` on any branch with nothing after it ?

Comment: Besides `* branch` or `* [new branch]` you can see `* tag` or `* [new tag]`. My `git fetch` output displays the last of these—and yes, I ran `git fetch` (which translated into the same as `git fetch origin`).

Comment: Thanks. I get the 2nd line. We created a new branch. About the first line. 1) What’s the purpose of depositing info to `FETCH_HEAD` what happens if that was not done? 2) “on the remote” what part of the 1st line has a mention of ‘remote’?

Comment: (1) The purpose of writing to `FETCH_HEAD` is two-fold: (1a) That's what `git fetch` originally did, before remote-tracking names were invented. In ancient Git (pre-1.5?) `FETCH_HEAD` is the *only* place these hashes went. That old behavior remains available today for those who still depend on it. (1b) Until `git pull` was rewritten in C, the `git pull` script depended on it. (2) Nothing in the first line *explicitly* says anything about the remote, but the remote *is* another Git repository. Being a Git repository, it has branches and tags. Your Git has called up the other Git. [continued]

Comment: The other Git has listed, for your Git, its branch and tag and other reference names (and their hash IDs). Your Git has chosen some or all of those references, to copy to your own Git somewhere (and to `FETCH_HEAD`). So `git fetch` shows you the names it saw in the *other* Git, such as `feature/8067`. It abbreviates them, but using the information towards the left, such as `* branch`, we can figure out what they got abbreviated from.

Comment: To see how this works, run `git ls-remote origin` and observe the output. That's the first data `git fetch` gets.

Answer (score 1):

The first line tells you that the fetch yielded a new branch on your local repo, and that you have its HEAD. The second says that the new branch is set up to track the remote branch. (You can have a local branch with the same name as a remote branch, but not be tracking the remote.)

The remote branch wasn't created there necessarily, but may have been pushed up from another developer, for example.

Comment: Thanks. 1) _The first line tells you that the fetch yielded a new branch on your local repo_ After I did that, I did `git branch`. It wasn't among my local branches. 2) What does tracking a remote mean? I suppose it means if I just do `git fetch` without mentioning what branch to fetch from then it will fetch from the branch its set to track from