# Pull default current doesn't work for GIT 2.3.8

Tags: git

I have added this: `git config --global pull.default current`

But when I do `git pull` I get all the branches from the `origin` remote. How can I make the default to work for `git pull`?

Comment: Is `pull.default` a valid configuration option? As far as I know, there is only `push.default`.

Comment: Given that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge` or `git rebase`, what exactly do you expect for `pull.default` to affect?  (There is no `pull.default` configuration item but there may be something that will do what you wanted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to [fetch only the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973924/6309), you need to specify it, since there is no pull.default policy (only push policies).
If your branch has an upstream branch

```
git fetch $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref @{upstream} | sed 's!/! !')
```

Note that `git pull` already pull (meaning merge) only the current branch (but fetches and then update all remote tracking branches)

You could also change [the refspec of the origin](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) to always fetch one branch, but that would not be the "current" one.