# Git fetch not recognizing remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a repository `myrepo` but when I try to fetch it, I cannot.  This repository exists on Github as well.  Fetching `origin/myrepo` causes an error as well.

Here is the error:

```
$ git fetch myrepo
fatal: 'myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ git fetch origin/myrepo
fatal: 'origin/myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ git branch
  calendar
  master
* myrepo
  routes
```

Clearly, as per the last command, the directory exists.

Comment: use "git branch -r" to see what remote branches actually exist for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to fetch everything:

```
git fetch origin
```

But if you want to [fetch only one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369199/6309):

```
git fetch <remotename> <remote branch>:refs/remotes/<remotename>/<local branch>
```

That is, in your case:

```
git fetch origin myrepo:refs/remotes/origin/myrepo
```

Answer (score 0):

`myrepo` is just a local branch in your local repository.

Use `git remote -v` to check what's the remote's name you have.