# git fetch only into specified target branch

Tags: git

I'm writing a test script for a CI/CD system and need to checkout the source and target branches of a pull request and do some verifications.
I would like to have fixed branch names in my local repo (`src` and `target`) and hence I use refspecs with a target branch for my fetches.
But additionally to my target branch git also fetches into a target branch with the original name of that branch (marked bold below). In the git fetch manpage I didn't even find a hint that git should behave this way.
This issue leads sometimes to name conflicts and I want to avoid that.

```
+ git fetch --no-tags -f origin feature/some-feature:refs/remotes/origin/src
From github.com:user/repo
 * [new branch]        feature/some-feature -> origin/src
 * [new branch]        feature/some-feature -> origin/feature/some-feature
 
+ git fetch --no-tags -f origin master:refs/remotes/origin/target
From github.com:user/repo
 * [new branch]        master    -> origin/target
 * [new branch]        master    -> origin/master
```

How can I make git stop fetching into branches with original names from remote and use only the target branch names I explicitly mention (how to remove bold lines)?

Comment: Why exactly is this necessary? It is good to be up to date on every branch.

Comment: @PeterNielsen The repository is >10gb big with many thousands of commits and also that many branches and hence I don't want every branch. To check a pull request I only need the source and target branches of that PR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fetch only one branch of a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository/26270966) is an answer. Duplicate question.

Comment: @PeterNielsen no, you didn't understand my question. I already fetch single branches all the time. My problem is the naming of the fetched branches.

Comment: View `git config -l` in the repository. There should be a line including `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. If there is, remove that config value.

Comment: @ElpieKay this seems to solve it. At least adding `--refmap=` to my fetch command does. Please add your comment as a solution so I can accept it. From the docs: `Providing an empty <refspec> to the --refmap option causes Git to ignore the configured refspecs and rely entirely on the refspecs supplied as command-line arguments.`