How to get `git fetch` to pull only the remote branch corresponding to the current local branch? Don't want it to pull in any other remote branches
Given
$localBranch = git branch --show-current
$remote = git config branch.$localBranch.remote
$remoteBranch = git config branch.$localBranch.merge
$remoteTrackingBranch = $remote/$remoteBranch

when I do git push, it seems to implicitly do git push <source>:<target> where

<source> := $localBranch, and
<target> := $remote $remoteBranch

This updates both the remote-tracking branch and the remote branch to match the local branch.

I would like for git pull to have a similar behavior. git pull does git fetch followed by git merge. So, I would like for git fetch (whether called explicitly, or via git pull) to parallel git push, i.e. I would like for git fetch to implicitly do git fetch <source>:<target> where

<source> := $remote $remoteBranch, and
<target> := $localBranch

This would updates both the remote-tracking branch to match the remote branch.
If doing git pull, the subsequent git merge would update the local branch to match the remote-tracking branch and remote branch.

Is there a way to induce this behavior? If so how? Maybe by editing the config file (git config --edit). Would I make an alias for fetch?

Currently, git fetch fetches many remote branches* to the local repo, which I do not want.
*Does this via git config -get-all remote.origin.fetch which looks like
...
+refs/heads/dev/jv/*:refs/remotes/origin/dev/jv/*
+refs/heads/feature/*:refs/remotes/origin/feature/*
+refs/heads/hotfix/*:refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/*
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master


Did you spend 10 seconds googling this? This is the first result after pasting your own question title in the Google search bar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository - git pull seems to accept the same format according go the git doc, so maybe try that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752253/13881506

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565941/13881506

Thanks! The answers in that post sill seem to require providing a refspec (<source>:<target>) for git fetch and git pull. This question is about whether, git fetch and git pull can be configured to behave do do git fetch <source>:<target> w/o having to explicitly specify <source> and <target>.
Perhaps my title is lacking.
