# Can someone further explain checking out of remote branches with git?

Tags: git

I've looked at a few questions here, notably this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch) but I'm still confused.

I have a server set up with a slow up-link that I access through an SSH tunnel.  On it, I cloned a bare repository of the Linux kernel (origin points to kernel.org).  I then cloned the bare repository on my home machine, checked out tag, created a branch ('test' say), made changes on that branch and finally pushed the changes to the bare repo on my server.

Now I'm at a client site and want to checkout the branch.  To avoid my slow uplink at the client site, I cloned the linux repo from the kernel.org and changed 'origin' to point to my server via the SSH tunnel.  *I can see the branch, but **can't check it out**:*

```
~/linux-3.0.y$ git version
git version 1.7.0.4
~/linux-3.0.y$ 
~/linux-3.0.y$ git status
# On branch master 
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
~/linux-3.0.y$ 
~/linux-3-0.y$ git remote show origin
git-user@localhost's password:
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git+ssh://git-user@localhost:48884/home/git-user/linux-3.0.y
  Push  URL: git+ssh://git-user@localhost:48884/home/git-user/linux-3.0.y
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    test    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master  new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
~/linux-3.0.y$ 
~/linux-3.0.y$ git checkout -b test origin/test
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/test' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

What I actually intended was to be able to work on the branch created at home at my client's site.  **What should I do (have done) to checkout this branch?**

Comment: Just to check, have you run `git fetch origin` yet?  (If not, `origin/test` won't have been created yet.)  It may help if you also include the output of `git branch -a` in your question, which shows both your local branches and your remote-tracking branches.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well first, it seems that you didn't fetch the branches.

Use `git branch -a` instead of `git remote show origin`.

If the test branch is missing, then do `git fetch --all`.

Now if you want to checkout a remote branch as a local branch with the same name, just do `git checkout BRANCH_NAME`, it will be automatically set up to track the origin.

Comment: more explicitly, without Git's DWIMery: `git checkout -b BRANCH --track origin/BRANCH`

Comment: That makes some sense to me ... I'm powering through some other confusions right now.