# How to checkout a remote branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Someone pushed a "new feature" branch to the shared repo:

```
git push -u new_feature_branch
```

Now, I would like to create a copy of this branch on my local machine in order to test the new feature.

What would be the easiest way to do this? (Do I need to `fetch` / `pull` before `checkout`?)

Comment: Might be duplicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I generally find it unnecessary to use `git fetch`. `git pull` is sufficient. `git pull` will synchronize your repository with the remote. The **new_feature_branch** will then be available.

`git checkout new_feature_branch` will notice the branch in origin and create a new local tracking branch for you and switch to that branch.

```
git pull
git checkout new_feature_branch
```

Comment: git pull == git fetch + git merge

Comment: use -b if you don't want a detached head

Answer (score 42):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
git fetch
git checkout -t origin/new_feature_branch
```

This is only done initially. From now on you can continue working with the branch as you do for the others you use.

Answer (score 16):

You need to fetch upstream changes so your local repository includes the relevant objects (`git fetch --all` or `git fetch <remote>`).

Afterwards you can perform a checkout using `git checkout <branch>` (if you like to do it explicitly, you can type `git checkout -b <branch> <remote>/<branch>`; the local name doesn't have to be the same as the remote). If you don't already have a local branch of that name, it will checkout the remote branch and track it.

As an alternative to this, you can use `git pull <remote> <branch>`, but this will - with default settings - merge the remote branch into your current, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I wonder why this answer says that you MUST use `fetch --all` and the top answer just mentions `fetch`. Which one is it?

Comment: @PetriSirkkala The answer does not say that you must use `--all`. `fetch --all` says fetching all remotes (if you have more than e.g. `origin`).

Answer (score 6):

```
git fetch && git checkout new_feature_branch
```

Comment: can you please look into this question if you have time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634111/magento-error-when-disable-module

Answer (score 0):

for synchronize your repository with the remote branch run `git fetch` then after fetching run `git checkout new_branch_name`
if you are using vs code add git Graph extension for diagnose the issue. It will help you in future use as well.