# Created Git branch with same name as one on remote

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch

I created a new branch called `table` in Git, but I didn't run `git fetch origin` before creating it.

It turns out someone created a branch called `table` before I did.

How can I delete the one I created and checkout theirs?

Comment: See [git checkout remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch/1783426#1783426) and [Git Branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
$ git branch -D table
$ git checkout -b table origin/table
```

Answer (score 0):

The -m flag will allow you to rename a branch.

```
git branch -m oldname newname
```