# Equivalent of "svn checkout" for Git

Tags: git, svn, git-checkout, svn-checkout

What Git command should I use to be equivalent to `svn checkout`?

```
git checkout(?)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate... or invalid question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch

Comment: Did you try `git checkout`? What happened? Also, an **EXCELLENT** resource for learning how to use Git is the [**FREE** online **Pro Git** book](http://git-scm.com/book). Recommended: chapters 1-3, 6-6.5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: I didn't try `git checkout`. I just wanna be sure about what command should I use because my repository has more than 2 GB.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is exactly what I wanted:

SVN

```
svn checkout svn://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk foo
# Make your changes
svn commit -m "my first commit"
```

Git

```
git clone git@github.com:pjhyett/foo.git
# Make your changes
git commit -a -m "my first commit"
git push
```

From
*[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)*

Answer (score 25):

[`git clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) is more of an analogue to `svn checkout` than [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).  `git checkout` just checks out a branch or commit from your local repository.  `git clone` makes a new copy of a remote repository.

Comment: +1, Just to emphasize, in 99% of case you'd do an `svn checkout` you'd need a `git clone`.