# git checkout from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I set up a GitHub project (`origin`).

I then cloned this repo into a bunch of different machines (ex. my local computer, a production environment, a staging environment, ect).

I make changes on my local machine, and push to `origin`.

Eventually, I merge my development branch into `origin/master`.

I then want to pull these changes from `origin/master` into my production environment, so;

```
root@production$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
root@production$ git remote
origin
root@production$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  ...
```

from here, I've tried everything;

```
git fetch
git checkout master
----------------------------------
git checkout origin/master
----------------------------------
git checkout -b origin/master HEAD
```

But none of them worked (ie, the changes were never reflected). It wasn't until I did

```
git pull origin master
```

that it finally worked. But I don't understand why I can't just checkout the master? Everything I'm reading on SO says to use `checkout` ([`git checkout remote branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch)) - I don't get it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch` fetches objects and updates your remote `origin/master`; it doesn’t change any local branches. To merge `origin/master` back into `master` after a fetch, you would use `merge`:

```
git merge origin/master
```

`git pull` is just a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`. You usually won’t even have to specify the branch and remote names; if you’ve set the upstream for the branch to `origin`, you can just run:

```
git pull
```

and it will assume you mean to fetch the upstream of the current branch and merge it into the current branch.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I get that - but why can't I checkout origin/master? Perhaps doing a `pull` is the right approach, but now I'm just curious why I can't checkout?

Comment: @Joney: You should be able to check out `origin/master`, but you’ll be in the “detached HEAD” state, and changes you make won’t automatically be reflected on `master`. (You’re not on `master` at that point.)

Comment: I have seen the detached HEAD message before. Whats the correct git command to use to do this?

Comment: @Joney: To go into the detached HEAD state? That’s it. `checkout` on something that’s a pointer to a commit, but not a local branch. (e.g. a remote branch or a commit hash.)