# How to see a newly created branch in a Chocolatey Fork on Github locally and subsequently push to this branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, chocolatey

**Summary**

- Github Chocolatey Repository has been forked to own Github account as Chocolatey-1
- A new branch `installchocolateyservice` has been created
- installchocolateyservice has been pulled
- A push to installchocolateyservice branch fails, while it works to push to the master
- `git branch` indicates that only the master is recognized

---

**Verbose**

*Extra branch created in Chocolatey Fork*

[image]

*Other branch than master pulled*

```
C:\chocolatey-1>git pull origin installchocolateyservice
remote: Reusing existing pack: 4611, done.
remote: Counting objects: 25, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
rRemote: Total 4636 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)eceiving objects: 100% (4636/4
Receiving objects: 100% (4636/4636), 21.86 MiB | 276.00 KiB/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (2792/2792), done.
From github.com:030/chocolatey-1
 * branch            installchocolateyservice -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      installchocolateyservice -> origin/installchocolateyservice
```

*Push to installchocolateyservice branch failed*

```
C:\chocolatey-1>git push origin installchocolateyservice
error: src refspec installchocolateyservice does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:030/chocolatey-1.git'
```

*Push to master works*

```
C:\chocolatey-1>git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

*Only master branch is recognized*

```
C:\chocolatey-1>git branch
* master

C:\chocolatey-1>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you deleted this question? I was in the middle of answering it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Checkout remote Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command

```
git branch
* master
```

doesn't show your new branch because it doesn't exist as a local branch yet, only as a remote-tracking branch. You'll be able to see it if you pass the `--remotes`/`-r` or the `--all`/`-a` option,

```
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/installchocolateyservice 
  remotes/origin/master
```

### Creating local branches from remote branches

If you wanted to create a local version of the branch, the correct way to do it would have been to use `git fetch` followed by a checkout, not `git pull`, because `git pull` is a fetch followed by a merge into your current branch.

So the proper command sequence is

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b installchocolateyservice origin/installchocolateyservice
```

Note that if you checkout a non-existent local branch `X`, and there is a remote-tracking branch called `origin/X`, then a new local branch `X` will be created from `origin/X` and set up to track it by default. So, in other words, instead of using the above commands, you can also do

```
git fetch origin
git checkout installchocolateyservice
```

Now that you have a proper local branch, you should be able to push to the remote one:

```bash
git push origin HEAD
# Or
git push origin installchocolateyservice
```