# Re-fork a repository on GitHub

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I've forked a repository on GitHub and have a quite an extensive commit/pull/push history, which I need to keep.

The owner of the main repository has created some new branches.  How can I clone these branches into my forked copy, without deleting the fork and cloning from scratch?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll want to add the other repository as a remote for your own one.

Got to where you've got your repository on your computer and open git Bash and do:

```
git remote add upstream <address of the repository you cloned from>
```

Then whenever you need to update your fork just do:

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

That will reapply whatever changes are on your current branch on top of any changes from the other repository. Note to make things easier I usually leave the master branch on my repository untouched and only work in branches. Then whenever I need to update I just rebase master and rebase my other branches on top of that.

Don't know about getting other branches for upstream though but this answer may be of help: [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch)

Comment: I think the parameters are the other way around? (At least this seems to have worked for me):

git remote add upstream <address of the repository you cloned from>

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're right. I'll fix that in my reply.