# deleted local branch of remote branch. How to reobtain local?

Tags: php, git, phpstorm

Total says mostly the issue i'm having.  Instead of clicking 'merge' I clicked 'delete'.  How do I undo this action / retrieve a new copy of this remote branch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just do `git fetch` and then `git checkout [branch]`? This will only work on Git ≥ 1.6.6.

Comment: this would be what you want.

Comment: i tried git fetch [name] but I get a fatal: [name] does not appear to be a git repository fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Comment: You don't need to specify a remote, origin will be used by default. So `git fetch` by itself is fine.

Comment: git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

Comment: Look at the solution provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch

Comment: Your answer was very useful and lead me on a quest to find the reason that this error would be present.  I used below, btw, as to my solution.  thx :D

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

to retrieve the remote branch and create a new local branch of this repo.