# How to check out a branch in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a Git repository at https://user_name@bitbucket.org/path/git.git.
This repository has a branch called `feature/myFeature`, which I want to check out. I have run

```
git init
```

in the desired folder, and then, according to Bitbucket, I need to run

```
git fetch && git checkout feature/myFeature
```

However, I get the following error,

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please,
>   specify either a URL or a remote name from which new revisions should
>   be fetched.

I guess I need to specify the repository, but I don't know how exactly to do this, and at the same time specify the branch.

What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a remote first (`git init` just created an empty local repo):

```
git remote add origin https://user_name@bitbucket.org/path/git.git
```

Then you can fetch and [checkout the remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/6309)