# fetch and checkout a remote git branch in just one command

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-fetch

If

- I have local repo with a remote `$REMOTE` already set up
- and a new branch `$BRANCH` exists on the remote repo that I haven't fetched, yet

can I fetch that branch **and** check it out into a tracking local branch of the same name **in a single command**?

I can achieve the desired result in *two* commands either with

```sh
git fetch $REMOTE $BRANCH
git checkout $BRANCH # or more explicitly git checkout -b $BRANCH $REMOTE/$BRANCH
```

or (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19442557/674064) to Question [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783405/674064)) with

```sh
git fetch $REMOTE $BRANCH:$BRANCH
git branch --set-upstream-to=$BRANCH $BRANCH
```

Comment: No, but [you can define an alias](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).

Comment: @Phillip If ,,no" is the answer, why not posting it as the answer?

Comment: @JosuaSchmid Because I don't consider a one-liner a good answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no builtin command, but you could define an alias in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  fetch-checkout = !sh -c 'git fetch $1 $2 && git checkout $2' -
```

Comment: @das-g: well, you could always do [`git checkout --track FETCH_HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or some variant of it

Comment: @das-g: I looked further into the topic, but I was unable to find a way to use `FETCH_HEAD` to create a tracking branch. Looks like you have to go with the alias

Comment: But it loose autocompletion. And I almost always use it beacuse I have easy-to-remember branches prefixes, but I can't remember its full name :(

Comment: You'd have to manually add this command to the bash autocompletion list (or whatever shell you are using).