# Git: How to update the master branch and switch to it in one step?

Tags: windows, git

I'm working on a project that's hosted on GitLab and uses issue/work branches and merge requests to bring that work into the master branch when it's done. Usually I work on issue branches. When it has been merged by GitLab, I need to switch to the current master to do a build, locally.

My workflow is this:

- Switch to master
- Pull from remote (--ff-only)
- Remove stale remote tracking branches
- Also remove their local tracking branches

There's also a client-side tool that watches the code directory and updates some files (CSS, JavaScript). When it sees a change in the first step (switch to master), I first need to wait for it to finish before going on (to avoid confusion). If there's a difference between the issue branch and the old master, there's a good chance that the difference will disappear when updating master (as that issue branch is now merged).

I'm looking for a way to switch to the already-updated master branch in one step. How can I do that with a `git` command? I want to bundle up all these actions in a batch file to avoid repeating all those manual steps in TortoiseGit every time.

This question is different from the suggested one in that the local master branch already exists. I'm not switching to a *new branch* from a remote, but to a branch that *already exists and it just behind the remote*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch and checkout a remote git branch in just one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392969/fetch-and-checkout-a-remote-git-branch-in-just-one-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Unless you write your own script (or use a Git alias to run multiple commands and/or scripts), you can't get this down to a single command, but you can get closer.  See the long section for many caveats: the biggest one is that it assumes you're *not already on `master`* when you do it.  If you are, the second step won't work (see the long section for what will).

```
git fetch -p &&
    git fetch . refs/remotes/origin/master:refs/heads/master &&
    git checkout master
```

will take care of the first three bullet points—not in the same order—with a single work-tree-updating `git checkout step`.

(Note that I split this into three lines for posting purposes, but as a Git alias using `!`, it's really all one big line.)

#### Long

There are several approaches, including actual, literal batch files (shell scripts on Unix-like systems, or .BAT files, or whatever) and aliases (as suggested by [Joe in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950890/git-how-to-update-the-master-branch-and-switch-to-it-in-one-step#comment111321597_62950890)).

> There's also a client-side tool that watches the code directory and updates some files ...

This is ... not necessarily a good idea, let's say. :-)

While `git checkout master` runs, it's changing various files.  Let's say that for some reason, it changes *one* of several files that the watcher watches, but then it pauses for a few minutes (or seconds, or microseconds, or some unit of time anyway).  While it is paused, the watcher tries to combine the multiple files that are now out of sync.

Maybe this is OK and self-correcting when Git un-pauses and finishes the checkout—but it might be better if you could make sure the update only happens when the checkout is done.

That aside, let's take a look at this particular series of commands, and be very concrete about which Git command you're using:

> - Switch to master

I assume this is `git checkout master`.

> Pull from remote (--ff-only)

I assume this is `git pull origin master --ff-only` or perhaps just `git pull --ff-only`.

> - Remove stale remote tracking branches

I'll assume for now that this is `git fetch --prune`.  If you are doing something different, you should include that in your question.

> - Also remove their local tracking branches

If I understand what you mean, this requires a script.  Note that this is somewhat dangerous: suppose you have your own branch `X` on which you are doing development.  This `X` is not related to anyone else's `X`.  Then someone creates *their own* `X`—using the same name—and sends it to the machine from which you `git fetch`.  You now have `origin/X`.  Then they *delete* their `X` (because they're done with it) and delete `origin/X`.  If you now have your script delete *your* `X`, because `origin/X` went away, that would probably be bad.

If you only delete your `X` when it explicitly has `origin/X` set as its upstream, this particular case won't occur—but if someone accidentally deletes *your* `origin/X` thinking it was *their* `origin/X`, the same problem crops up again, and this time that particular protection does not work.

Anyway, with all that aside, let's look at the variant I suggested above.

#### `git fetch -p`

This updates all your `origin/*` names,<sup>1</sup> including `origin/master`, without affecting any *files* in your working tree.  The `-p` is short for `--prune`, so it deletes any `origin/*` names that no longer have a corresponding branch in the Git over at the URL stored under the name `origin`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I assume here that you have only one *remote*, which is named `origin`.  If you have more than one remote, use `git fetch origin -p` to make sure you're fetching specifically from the one named `origin`.  I also assume you have not configured your Git to be a single-branch clone.

---

#### `git fetch . refs/remotes/origin/master:refs/heads/master`

This rather magic-looking command tells your Git to call *itself* up.  That is, the special name `.` refers to *your own Git repository*.  We are using this to trick your Git into fast-forwarding *your* `master` branch based on your updated `origin/master`.  The final argument is what does this: we say to your Git: *OK, my Git, when you talk to that other Git, find out what commit its `refs/remotes/origin/master` identifies.  Then, if that's a fast-forward operation, update *my* `refs/heads/master` to match.*

Of course, the "other Git" your Git is talking to is itself—so this means *fast-forward my `master` from my `origin/master`*.<sup>2</sup>  It's roughly equivalent to:

```
git checkout master && git merge --ff-only origin/master && git checkout -
```

except that no actual checking-out occurs: no files in your work-tree change.

---

<sup>2</sup>You might wonder why some of these use `origin/master` and some use `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  The longer one is just the *full spelling* of the name.  When using `git fetch`, it's wise to use the full spellings.  In fact, in general, in scripts, you might want to use full spellings more often, but specifically `git fetch` can become confused if the *other* Git you talk to accidentally has both a branch and a tag with the same name, for instance.  So I'm illustrating the full names with `git fetch`.  You'll use it to talk to your own Git, so if you don't mix up your tags and branch names or otherwise create ambiguity, you won't actually *need* the full names.  But it's a good habit with `git fetch`.

---

#### The above fails if you're on your `master`

The `git fetch` command will refuse to fetch into whatever branch name you have checked out.  So if you *are* on `master`, this `git fetch .` trick will fail.

In a way, this is OK!  If you *are* on your `master`, what you should do instead is run:

```
git merge --ff-only origin/master
```

or anything equivalent.  This is what your `git pull --ff-only` does: first it runs `git fetch` (without the `-p` and limited to fetching only the other Git's `master`); then it runs `git merge --ff-only`.

#### A more complete version

A more complete version of this sequence, then, is to first check: *Which branch am I on?*  To do that, you can use either of two Git commands:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

or:

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

Both of these will print `master` if you are currently on your own `master` branch.  The difference between them is what they do if you're on no-branch-at-all: e.g., in the middle of a rebase, when you are in "detached HEAD" state.  In that case, the second command—the `git symbolic-ref` one—errors out, while the first one just prints `HEAD`.

If you'd like to avoid doing any of this when in such a state, use the second command and check for failure.  Otherwise, use the first one.  I'll illustrate just the first one here:

```
if test $(git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD) = master; then
    # already on master - use alternative strategy
    git fetch -p && git merge --ff-only refs/remotes/origin/master
else
    # not currently on master: use fancy tricks to update
    git fetch -p &&
        git fetch . refs/remotes/origin/master:refs/heads/master &&
        git checkout master
fi
```

The above, while untested, should be suitable as a shell script.  If you have Git installed, you have the ability to run shell scripts—or you can turn the above into a very long Git alias, using `!` and the appropriate set of semicolons.

Comment: Thank you very much! This already does almost all of my needs very well. I wrote it in a batch script for now but I like the idea that I can write Bash scripts through tools included in Git for Windows. About the old local branches: They follow the format `^[0-9]+-` because they're normally managed by GitLab and it's our project convention to follow that. Nobody is "supposed" to create local branches with such names. I guess the output of `git fetch -p` could be parsed for this. Bash would probably be required then. I'll think about that. Already saving much time now.