# how could I pull from remote branch locally

Tags: git

Assume I want to pull from remote branch named "FC-1000". I could create a new branch locally by "git checkout -b FC-1000" and then pull origin from remote. But locally, which branch should I be to create the new branch? 
For example, If I'm on FC-2000 and do "git checkout -b FC-1000", I will create the new branch FC-1000 from FC-2000.

Answer (score 0):

Following the GitHub documentation, this would be the best command to run:
git branch -f new_local_branch_name upstream/remote_branch_name

It'll create a new branch and sync it to the remote branch in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the remote branch is named `origin/some-branch`. If you have a recent version of Git, you can just type `git checkout some-branch`, and a local branch named `some-branch` will be automatically created that tracks `origin/some-branch`. It does not matter what branch you are on when you run this command.

Comment: You may need to `git fetch origin` first so that you're up to date with origin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the official recommendation is: `git checkout -b [branch] [remotename]/[branch]`or the shorthand `git checkout --track origin/serverfix`. (Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) You may have to do a `git fetch` first, but I haven't been able to find official documentation saying so...

There's a lot of good commentary on your situation here: [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch).

Here's the full official git instructions: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

To answer the "letter" of your question: Most likely you would want to run your `git checkout -b` from the master branch. Otherwise it's whatever branch FC-1000 was created from.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you need to create a tracking branch.
Just perform the following steps:

```
git fetch
git checkout --track origin/FC-1000
```

This will create a branch which will track the branch at origin.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a local branch to pull. Just run

```
git pull origin FC-1000
```

From the branch to which you want to merge.