# How to track remote branch that is not mine git

Tags: git

So let's say someone made a remote branch called fooBranch

I looked through other posts and found

```
git fetch --all
git branch -a
```

and was able to see

```
remotes/origin/fooBranch
```

and I was able to check it out using

```
git checkout fooBranch
```

using this post [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch)
the problem is, I want to be able to track the branch and push changes to the branch.

I looked through tons of different posts to setup upstreams and tracking and they didn't work. such as this [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)
I use git 2.1.0, I already spent an hour trying to figure this out T_T, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `git pull fooBranch`

Comment: I did git checkout fooBranch and git pull fooBranch , i get fatal does not appear to be a git repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all remote branches:

```
git fetch
```

Create a local branch and track it (fetch/push)

```
git checkout -b fooBranch origin/fooBranch
```