# Git: how to checkout new remote branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-checkout, git-remote

I'm trying to checkout a remote branch which doesn't exist locally.

```
git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name
```

gives:

```
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'branch_name' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/branch_name' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

`git branch -a` doesn't show the branch I'm trying to checkout.

How can I checkout the remote branch locally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkout remote Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch)

Comment: I did try the the solution from that question, but it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure to do a `git fetch` before trying to check out the branch...

Comment: @zoe why is my homepage suddenly nothing but questions you've edited?

Comment: @hobbs cleaning up the [tag:checkout] tag.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
git remote update
git fetch
git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name
```

Your local repo is not aware of the remote branch.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Checkout still gives the same error message(fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'branch_name' at the same time).

Comment: The first two commands work, but `git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name` just gives the same error "fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'branch_name' at the same time." on git 2.12

Answer (score 2):

If `git branch -a` doesn't show the branch you want, it doesn't exist on the remote either - the `'origin/branch_name' which can not be resolved` message confirms that.

First, run `git fetch origin` to sync your local snapshot of the remote and see if the remote branch appears in `git branch -a`. In that case your current command should work, or there are many other versions in [Checkout remote Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch).

If the remote branch doesn't appear, you'll need to create it with

```
git checkout -b branch_name
git push -u origin branch_name
```

You might also want to check `git remote -v` to make sure your remote exists and is called `origin`.

Comment: The remote branch definitely does exist. git branch -a shows:
  develop
* CurrentBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop

I did try git fetch origin but it didn't make a difference. 

git remote -v shows: 
origin https://github.com/reponame/reponame.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/reponame/reponame.git  (push)

Comment: It looks like the only branch `origin` is aware of is `develop`. Which branch are you trying to check out that you see `origin` having?

Comment: The branch i'm trying to checkout is called develop2. I can see the branch on github, but it doesn't show up in my command outputs.

Comment: Does `develop2` exist on GitHub in the same `user/repo` your `origin` is pointing to? If the repository was forked, it might be in a different copy that you need to add as a second remote.

Comment: It does exist in the same user/repo. I tried git branch -a on my laptop and develop2 does show up. So it's only a problem on my current pc.

Comment: It sounds like something funny might have happened to your first computer's copy then, which'll be hard to help debug much further. I'd try `git fetch --all` and compare `.git/config` between your machines, then consider a fresh `git clone`.

Comment: I did a fresh git clone, and now I can checkout.