# How to check out a single remote branch into a directory?

Tags: git, github-pages

**Introduction**

I have a local repository with a remote branch called `gh-pages`:

```
$ git branch -v -a
* master                  edfa5f3 Adds README for JSDoc.
  remotes/origin/HEAD     -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages f7ab217 Switch to JSDoc 3.4.0-dev (Sun, 14 Jun 2015 18:49:07 GMT)
  remotes/origin/master   edfa5f3 Adds README for JSDoc.
```

And I can checkout a single branch from the remote origin into a single directory:

```
$ git clone `git ls-remote --get-url` --branch gh-pages --single-branch gh-pages
```

After that I have the `gh-pages` branch in the `gh-pages` directory. This works fine. The reason why I need to use two branches simultaneously is my source code documentation. The generation of the source code documentation takes the source code from the currently checked out branch and generates the HTML into the `gh-pages` branch.

The disadvantage is, that I have to push the two branches independently to the remote origin.

**Problem**

Now I tried to get the same setup with just my local repository. But when I try to clone the `gh-pages` branch from my local repository it fails:

```
$ git clone . --branch gh-pages --single-branch gh-pages
Cloning into 'gh-pages'...
warning: Could not find remote branch gh-pages to clone.
fatal: Remote branch gh-pages not found in upstream origin
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

After some reading I understood that the `gh-pages` branch is missing in my local repository. So I tried to fetch it as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/402322). But the fetch without checkout seems to do nothing:

```
$ git fetch
$ git branch
* master
```

I still do not have the `gh-pages` branch. I do not want to check out the remote branch, I just want to have it to be able to clone it. How do I fetch the branch for clone instead of checkout?

After that I want to push from my `gh-pages` clone into my local repository. And when I do a push from my local repository to the remote origin both branches, the `master` and the `gh-pages` branch, should be pushed.

Is this possible to do or do I have a misunderstanding about the way `fetch` and `push` actually work?

Comment: `git worktree add` might be a better solution for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using same repository to host source code (on master) and documentation (on gh-pages).

My sources code folders tree is something like :

```
##
--src
--dist
--documentation
--.gitignore
--package.json
-- ...
```

The `documentation` folder is where the documentation is generated.
I've added it to `.gitignore` so it'll not be present in `master` branch.

This sources repository points to `origin` with `master` checked out.

Now the `documentation` folder is another git repository pointing to `origin`, but it has `gh-pages` branch checked out.

Workflow summary is `code in master` -> `generate doc` -> `commit and push master` -> `commit and push gh-pages`.