# how to use the git plugin to checkout a specific branch

Tags: jenkins

How can I use the Jenkins Git plugin to check out a specific branch? I have installed Jenkins and I use the GIT plugin to clone a repository. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout remote Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch)

Comment: Not really duplicate.  OP wants how to use Jenkins Git plugin. The linked question is specifically on git.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option to pass branch name in [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)/ [Git Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin).

This accepts build parameters. So you could add parameter to the job, say with BRANCH_NAME and pass it to git plugin. Options are Just above the "Repository Browser" setting

[image: click the image to see the full picture.]

Here is with build parameter
[image: with parameter called BRANCH_NAME]

Answer (score 1):

In "Branches to build" you have to:

- put the branch name or `*/${GIT_BRANCH}`
- uncheck "Lightweight checkout" checkbox, which is below "Script Path"

Answer (score 0):

Add the branch name in Branches to build bloc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u08TW.png)