# How do I checkout a remote branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

When I `git branch` I only see 'master', 'v2/branch1', and 'v2/master', but when I `git branch -r` I see a lot more branches that come after origin. If I were to want to work in one of these remote branches, do I just git checkout ? Would that automatically change my working directory and index to that branch and set up the tracking branch for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout remote Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch remote`

`git checkout --track -b local_branch_name origin/branch_name`

Comment: can you explain the purpose of fetching? Doesn't my git branch -r mean that I'm already tracking all of these remote branches?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

```
git branch -r
git checkout <branch name>
```