# steps to switching to another branch in git from commandline

Tags: git

when I am in the commandline, what is the command to display all the branches and also switch from one git branch to another git branch?

I dont want to create a new branch, i just want to switch to an existing branch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check out a remote Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-to-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listing all branches [non-remote branches]:

```
git branch
```

switching to another branch:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```