# Change remote branch of repository and pull only the changes

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote, git-fetch

I have a remote repository that has a lot of branches. Every time there is a new version, a new branch is created. How can I, when a new version is available, change the branch and pull the changes avoiding to clone it all again. I want to only download the new committs.

Comment: `git fetch` does not "clone it all again".

Comment: But what I want is to change the branch and sync it. So that I can use pull, push, etc. Not only fetch the commits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check out a remote Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-to-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Executive Summery:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout new-version`
```

Where `origin` is the remote name and `new-version` is the branch name.

### Details:

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) for `git fetch` says:

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more
>   other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their
>   histories. Remote-tracking branches are updated.

This basically means that it goes and downloads the history of the repository from the remote. However, a repository can have multiple remotes, so `git fetch` can fetch either one or more of them using the `--all` flag.

> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is
>   also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that
>   you are interested in. This default behavior can be changed by using
>   the --tags or --no-tags options... By using a refspec that fetches tags explicitly,
>   you can fetch tags that do not point into branches you are interested
>   in as well.

Meaning that if you had, for example, branches *A, B & C* on the remote, and on local you were working on branch *C*. If you `git fetch origin C`, by default, this will also fetch the tags pointing to that branch, but it will not fetch those related to other branches, for instance *A* and *B*.
If you want to fetch all tags, you just add the `--tags` to the command.

Finally,

> When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be
>   used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current
>   branch.

#### Resources:

- `git fetch` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), it's all well explained.
- The Git Pro [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches), chapter 3.5 goes through this.
- You may also want to look at this related question as well: [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: Does this work with tags? Also, does this only fetch the commits needed to get up-to-date or all of the new ones?

Comment: You can think of _tags_ as branches, so yes, it does work with tags provided that you add the `--tags` to the `fetch` command.
This fetches the changes for the whole repository, but you can also fetch only specific branches if you like by adding the name of the branch. i.e `git fetch origin branch-x`

Comment: Usually you don't even need `--tags`: Git has some magic (I think "overly magic"—it's nearly inexplicable in terms of precisely what happens when) code to try to guess which tags to copy during normal `git fetch`, that mostly Just Works to get you the tags too. But use `git fetch --tags` if for some reason a tag is missing, and you will get it.

Comment: @Ayman Nedjmeddine and does this work to fetch the changes from a tag that doesn't exist in the local repository because it's newer?

Comment: @Ayman Nedjmeddine Last cuestion, can I then use git pull and the new tag will get pulled, and not the old one?

Comment: @MatiHalperin, I've detailed my answer more, I hope this helps better.
Please feel free to ask if something's not clear, otherwise please mark my answer ;)

Comment: That is an explanation of how fetch works, but it is not the solution I need. I have a repository which I cloned from a remote. I used: "git clone -b tag-x remote-repo". Now I want to change "tag-x" to "tag-y" and "git pull" the changes. I hope you understand what I need

Comment: That means you still have not understood. I have explained what `fetch` does and linked to the difference between it and `pull`.  
Anyways:  

`git clone -b tag-x remote`  
`.... do work ....`  
`git fetch origin`  
`git checkout tag-y`  
`git merge origin/tag-y`  
`... keep working on tag-y ...`  

OR

`git clone -b tag-x remote`  
`.... do work ....`  
`git checkout tag-y`  
`git pull origin tag-y`  
`... keep working on tag-y ...`  

That is what you want to do right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. But, if possible, use only `git pull` instead of `git pull origin tag-y`