# How do I get files from GitHub branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have pushed some files to "test" branch from my computer #1 (GitHub shows that branch with all pushed files).
I now want to get them on my computer #2. I tried fetching, however it doesn't do anything.
All I get is:

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin

$
```

How do I get branches and files on computer #2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sync git pull request from another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556053/how-to-sync-git-pull-request-from-another-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sh
git checkout test
```

This changes your current branch to the branch `test`, where your files are on.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use `git pull`.

Comment: Note that `git pull` requires the user to have checked out the desired branch before doing the pull.