# How to clone a git repository with all branches?

Tags: git

I have a server containing a git repository with several branches.
I checked on the server git with "git branch -r" and it displays:
origin/HEAD
origin/develop
origin/neatUI
origin/iOS
... and some more

If I clone this repository with:
"git clone [path_to_server]/ATS ATS"
I receive a repository just containing "develop".
"git branch -a" shows:
* develop
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
remotes/origin/develop

All other branches are missing.

If I clone the repository with the --mirror option all branches are present but I cannot work with them.
"git branch -a" shows:
remotes/origin/HEAD
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/neatUI
remotes/origin/iOS
... and the rest

If I try to checkout a branch git tells me 
"fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

I also tried "SourceTree" to clone the repoistory but also SourceTree creates only the "develop" branch.

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: A mirror clone is a bare clone, you can't check out branches in it.

Comment: You have a server repository. You run `git branch -r` in that repo. Running `git branch -r` does not list the branches in that repo. It lists the remote branches. Ie. `develop`, `iOS` and `neatUI` are all branches in some other repository which your server repository was cloned from. To list the branches in your server repo, you should run just `git branch` without the `-r` flag.

Comment: git branch only shows "develop". Looks like you are on the right track! :)
How can I add the other branches?

Comment: You could add the origin of your server repo as a remote to your newly cloned repo:
`git remote add origin2 <url from which your remote repo was cloned>`
(`origin2` here is just a name which you can choose to be whatever you want). Then you could fetch the branches from that remote `git fetch origin2`. After this, if you do `git branch -r` in your cloned repo, you should see remote tracking branches for both remote repos: `origin/develop
origin2/develop
origin2/neatUI
origin2/iOS`

Comment: Perfect! I must admit that I did not use the commands but realised it with "git gui". I solved it in git gui with >Create new branch >activate "Match Tracking Branch name" >Choose the desired branch from the "Tracking Branch" list.
Thank you so much for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 9):

There are a few separate, but intertwined, key concepts here.

The first is that while Git has *branch names*, that's not all that Git has (and for that matter, the term *branch* is ambiguous: see also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)).  Git also has *tags* and what Git calls *remote-tracking branch names*, and these all fall into a general category called *references*.

- A branch name like `master` is simply a reference whose ***full*** name starts with `refs/heads/`.
- A remote-tracking branch name like `origin/iOS` is a reference whose ***full*** name starts with `refs/remotes/`, followed by the name of the remote itself (`origin`) and another slash.  The *last* part, `iOS`, is something your Git normally *copies from another Git*.

  (The *remote* part of this is an almost-arbitrary string.  You can invent your own remote names.  However, the fact that the name of the remote gets a slash added afterward is tied to the reason you should be careful about using slashes in your remote names.)
- To complete this particular list, a tag name like `v1.0` is simply a reference whose ***full*** name starts with `refs/tags/`.  There are yet more forms of references (`refs/notes/` is for Git's `git notes`, and GitHub uses `refs/pull/` for instance) but branch, tag, and remote-tracking branches are all built in, and standard, and most importantly, highly visible—so you should know about them.

When you run `git branch`, Git finds all your `refs/heads/` reference names and shows them with `refs/heads/` stripped off.  When you run `git branch -r`, Git finds all your `refs/remotes/` references and shows them with `refs/remotes/` stripped off.  When you run `git branch -a`, Git finds both, and shows the first with `refs/heads/` stripped but shows the second with just `refs/` stripped.  (Why?  Who knows!  It's Git being gitty. :-) )

This explains why you see what you see, but not what happens with `git clone --mirror`, nor why you can `git checkout iOS` and suddenly have a new `refs/heads/iOS`; and for that we need two more items, about *refspecs* (as used with `git fetch` and `git push`), and about [what Git calls *DWIM*, or Do What I Mean, in `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1783405/1256452).

To keep this short: a *refspec* is just a pair of references, separated by a colon, and sometimes with one part replaced with `*`.  For instance, `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` is a refspec.  You can prefix a refspec with a leading plus sign as well; this sets the `--force` flag.  Both `git fetch` and `git push` work with refspecs (and both have a `--force` flag of their own, which effectively adds a `+` to any refspecs you give on the command line).  The reference before the colon is the *source* and the reference after the colon is the *destination*, and this matters because there are *two* Gits involved in `git fetch` and `git push`: yours, and some other Git.

When you `git fetch`, the source references are the other Git's references and the destination ones are yours.  When you `git push`, the source references are yours and the destination ones are theirs.

Using `git clone --mirror` tells your Git to set up a *bare* repository (which I'll leave undefined here) and to set up `+refs/*:refs/*` as the refspec for `git fetch`.  This copies *all* the references from the other Git at `origin`, but it means you cannot have your own branches: your Git is now an exact copy of theirs, and every time you run `git fetch` you *replace* everything you have with ... an exact copy of theirs, again.

**The main point of most `git clone` operations is to get an *inexact* copy of "their Git".**  The fundamental idea here is that you want all of *their* branch names to become *your* remote-tracking branch names.  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`; their `iOS` becomes your `origin/iOS`.

This leaves no room for *their* `origin/*`, because your inexact-copy has *its own* `origin/*`.  If you want to get their remote-tracking branches, you can—but you need to name them something else!

Once you do have your (non-mirror) clone, and their *`whatever`* becomes your `origin/whatever`, you can `git checkout whatever` and the DWIM action I mentioned (and linked) above comes into play, creating a new local *`whatever`* using your own `origin/whatever`—which you copied from their *`whatever`*!

Comment: That's a cool explanation of git concepts and answers their question about Y but it does not in any way answer the original question about problem X: How can you get a clone with local branches that match the current state of all of the remote's branches.

Comment: @Atemu: that's because the answer is "don't do that". :-) (The secondary answer is: if you must do that, use `git clone --mirror`, and then don't *work in the clone*.)

Answer (score 1):

Be rest assured if you cloned with `git clone <url>` all the branches are there in your working tree. You just need to strip origin/ when you want to checkin into other branch. For example, if you want to checkout iOS, do `git checkout iOS`

`git branch -r` shows all remote branches on the repository

`git branch -a` shows remote as well as local branches(if you created any in your local repo)

Comment: If I just clone the repo (without --mirror)  there is no iOS branch.
"git checkout iOS" produces "error: pathspec 'iOS did not match any file(s) known to git.r)"

Comment: How are you switching your branch ?

Comment: How can I assure that all branches are there? As I told before "git branch -a" only shows "develop"...

Comment: If you can see the branches git branch -r, just do a checkout to the one you want to

Comment: I can't see them. "git branch -r" only shows develop, too.

Comment: How did you clone the repo ?

Comment: "git clone [path_to_server]/ATS ATS" (see above)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I had previously cloned my repo with `--branch <branch-name>` or `--depth 1` options.
This will set the config entry for `remote.origin.fetch` to be `+refs/heads/<branch-name>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>` or `+refs/heads/<default-branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<default-branch>` respectively.

`<default-branch>` will usually be `main` or `master` or in case of OP `develop`.

You can check with this command:

```
git config --get remote.origin.fetch
```

Replace `origin` if your remote is named differently, see `git remote -v`.

You can update the setting with

```
git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can also edit the config in your configured editor with `git config -e`.

```ini
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<some-user>/<some-repo>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now `git fetch` should fetch all the remote branches (and associated tags).

For details see [@torek s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525312/13319671)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with repo on `github.com` with 2 branches. The solution below is based on a [demo repository](https://github.com/ugmurthy/demo) on `github.com` created solely for the purpose of this answer.

The `demo.git` repo has two branches named `first` and `second` contain only one file `README.md` the content of which is different each of the branches.

Clone the repository, list the branches, switch to the branch of interest.
Note: additional comments below are prefixed with `##`

```
## clone demo repo to local machine
$ git clone git:github.com:ugmurthy/demo.git
Cloning into 'demo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (9/9), done.

$ cd demo

## show local branches
$ git branch
* main

## show remote branches (github.com)
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  origin/first
  origin/main
  origin/second

## show both local and remote branches
$ git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/first
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/second


$ cat README.md 
# Demo

## switching branch 
$ git switch first
Branch 'first' set up to track remote branch 'first' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'first'

## Note that we now have first as a local branch
$ git branch 
* first
  main

$ cat README.md
# Demo
## FIRST BRANCH

$ git switch second
Branch 'second' set up to track remote branch 'second' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'second'
$ cat README.md 
# Demo
## SECOND BRANCH

$ git branch 
  first
  main
* second
```

References:

1. [git reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)
2. [How to clone a specific branch from github](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-clone-or-download-a-specific-branch-from-github/)

Answer (score -1):

1- Install Github CLI

2- Login with your account: `gh auth login`. follow to the process.

3- Make a folder in any place. example in the root `~/BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME`

```
gh repo list Organizaion_Repo_Name --limit 1000 | while read -r repo _; do   
gh repo clone "$repo" "$repo";
cd "$repo" && for BRANCH in $(git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master); do git branch --track "${BRANCH#remotes/origin/}" "${BRANCH}"; done; 
cd "~/BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME";done
```