# Unable to checkout branch that is on remote

Tags: git

I have a curious issue with a branch in github that is on my remote, e.g.

```
$ git branch -r
...
adler/issue-761__NLM
...
```

But when I try to checkout the branch, I get an error

```
$ git checkout issue-761__NLM
error: pathspec 'issue-761__NLM' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have tried `git fetch` etc, but it does not seem to resolve the issue. Curiously, I can explicitly checkout the branch from the remote, but this puts me in a detached head state

```
$ git checkout adler/issue-761__NLM
...    
HEAD is now at 94df12a... CONTRIB: Updates to NLM functional
```

How do I go about to resolve this issue so that I can check out the branch locally and work on it?

Edit: I've been told that is is a duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch). That is not the case, specifically I can in fact perform `git checkout adler/issue-761__NLM` and further, `git fetch` does not solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: Edit: updated question to explain why that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout issue-761__NLM` doesn't work because (most probably) there is no local branch named `issue-761__NLM`.

You can either [create the local branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and after that [check it out](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
$ git branch issue-761__NLM adler/issue-761__NLM
$ git checkout issue-761__NLM
```

Or, you can do both operations in a single command by running [`git checkout` with the correct arguments](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt):

```
$ git checkout -b issue-761__NLM
```

If there is no ambiguity where the remote branch(es) named `issue-761__NLM` points to, behind the scene, this command runs the two commands listed above.

---

#### Why it used to work?

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt) for `git checkout <branch>` says:

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

Please note the *"exactly one remote"* magic formula.
I guess you just added a secondary remote that also contains the `issue-761__NLM` branch.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the issue. Do you have any idea why I can fail to get a local branch? In all of my git history I've always been able to simply do `git checkout mybranch` and it gave me the correct result.

Comment: The second option assumes that the correct start point is checked out, and still doesn't set up tracking.  The correct shorthand (when just `checkout branch_name` doesn't work) would be `checkout --track remote/branch_name`

Comment: The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt) for `git checkout <branch>` says *"If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`"* -- I guess you just added a secondary remote that also contains the `issue-761__NLM` branch.

Comment: TriskalJM, had "you cannot accept within", done now. axiac, that does indeed seem to be the correct explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the "shorthand" that automatically creates local branches from remote branches isn't applicable in this case.  I think the most likely reason would be if you have a second remote that also has a branch named `issue-761__NLM`

You can specify that `adler/issue-761__NLM` is indeed the correct remote branch to track by saying

```
git checkout --track adler/issue-761__NLM
```

Adding `--track` to the checkout will tell git to create the local branch and set up tracking, rather than put you in detached HEAD state.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the issue. There are indeed two remote branches named `issue-761__NLM`.