# git switching repository/branches from master

Tags: git

I'm not experienced with git. I cloned a master branch of a project via 
`git clone --link--` and now in my git bash window I see: `/c/app/project (master)` so I'm in the master. Now I want to switch to an existing branch (say test) and do a pull to get the latest changes. When I type `git checkout test` I get `error: "error: pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.` how can I switch the branch

(since this was marked as duplicate, I checked the supposed answer and that did not solve my problem. It seems that I'm unable to move out of the master branch of my project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: possible duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get familiar first with basic git. This is one of the possible resource which you can print and put beside your workstation.

[Git cheat sheet](https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf)

You can use

> `git fetch` if you want to just get remote branches

or you can use

> `git pull` to sync the local with remote branches