# gitflow pulling and work with remote branch

Tags: git

I'm using gitflow, and I changed of computer, my feature called 'migration' is showed like remote branch

```
git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/migration
```

what is the right way to pull that branch, and complete the work, then do commits and push. I was using gitkraken, but i feel have bugs when you are in complex scenaries and with more than one features open, do the things very automatically in the wrong way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: the answer duplicate is confuse

Comment: the duplicate answer is very confused, i need only a clear answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `git checkout feature/migration` and it will create the branch locally then set up upstream.

You'll be able to work on it as usual, make changes, add, commit and push without additional steps.

Comment: accort to duplicate question link, is not secure if there is more one remote branch, there is not better use the complete name ? something like: git checkout remotes/origin/feature/migration  , so i'm sure ?

Comment: No, if you do that you won't create a local counterpart for the remote branch. You seem afraid of something but I can't figure out what.