# How do I ensure I am actually pulling a different release?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting frustrated because I have a friend that is telling me the app of a certain branch off Bitbucket is working a certain way for him. I had a newer release.

So I decided to do:

`git checkout -b release/3.5.1`

and

`git pull origin release/3.5.1`

and I got this response:

```
 * branch              release/3.5.1 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

I have never pulled this branch before, how can it be up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a new branch (with the `-b` flag). Instead of doing so, just checkout the branch from origin:

```
git checkout origin/release/3.5.1
```

If that results in a pathspec (branch not found) error, first do `git fetch` to retrieve the remote branch references.

Doing a pull as you did results in the remote branch being merged into the local branch *only if there was a tracking arrangement created*. In this case, there wasn't. You could set it up that way manually when you create the branch:

```
--track origin/release/3.5.1
```

That's really more work than necessary, though.

Comment: If I don't use the `-b` flag and just `git checkout origin/release/3.5.1` and if that results in a pathspec do, I do a `git fetch release/3.5.1`?

Comment: No. Fetch just gets the list. You then do the checkout.

Comment: I asked because I actually tried that before and it did not get me a list of all the branches, thats why I started to do it the way I described above.

Comment: It won't report branches that you have already fetched, just new and updated ones.

Comment: there are plenty of branches with this project that I have never fetched before, most branches I will probably not even need, but `git fetch` does not grab any of them.

Comment: It's starting to sound like your origin config is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing `git checkout release/3.5.1` would do the trick if you are using git >= 1.6.6

> - "git checkout frotz" when there is no local branch "frotz" but there
>     is only one remote tracking branch "frotz" is taken as a request to
>     start the named branch at the corresponding remote tracking branch.

So this will:

1. create a new local branch at the start of the remote branch
2. set it to follow the remote branch

<sup>*Taken from [this original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1787014/6320039).*</sup>

---

*NOTE:* [isherwood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348381/6320039) `git checkout origin/release/3.5.1` idea should be better if you don't want to keep a branch locally.