# How to pull older branch?

Tags: git

Remotely I have several branches, such as master, 12.0 and 13.0.   13.0 is ahead of 12.0, which is again ahead of master.

Locally I only have the branch 13.0, which is up to date with the remote branch.

Now I would also like to have the 12.0 branch locally.
So I enter `git checkout -b 12.0` and then `git pull origin 12.0`. However, the first command creates a local branch 12.0 based on 13.0, and consequently `git pull` produces an error.

So how can I get the remote 12.0 branch on my local machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this command separately in different folder to pull that particular branch.

```
git pull origin --branch <your branch name>
```

If you want to pull that branch in same project folder then use :

```
git fetch origin <your branch name>

git checkout <your branch name>
```

If you face any error try

```
git checkout -b <your branch name> --track origin/<your branch name>
```

Comment: Before the pull, should I first do a git checkout or something to create a branch?

Comment: No. This command will simply pull that particular branch and will not have connection with already pulled different branch

Comment: After this, the 12.0 local branch has the content of the 13.0 branch

Comment: Check I have updated my answer. Hope it works this time

Comment: That last line gives the error: "fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch '12.0' at the same time."

Comment: Please remove local 12.0 branch and firstly run fetch command. Then run command which I updated at last

Comment: It's strange that none of those are working. Please try updating git version

Comment: `git branch -D 12.0`, then `git fetch origin 12.0` and then `git checkout -b 12.0 --track origin/12.0`. The last gives the error: "fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch '12_tocs' at the same time."

Comment: Try executing ```git pull --all``` this will pull all branches from origin and merge with local copies

Comment: It worked after making the following change: Instead of "origin" I was actually using the url to the repo. Setting up the git remote origin, and trying it again actually using "origin" in the command, worked.

Comment: Two notes, one on the answer itself, and one on your own comment above: `--branch` is not an option to `git pull`, and `--all` is passed to `git fetch`, and it means *all remotes*, not *all branches*. It looks like Nick's main issue was not using the name `origin` and hence not getting any remote-tracking names.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, based on [your own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088851/how-to-pull-older-branch#comment104415577_59088963), it appears that the answer was to create a *remote* first:

> It worked after making the following change: Instead of "origin" I was actually using the url to the repo. Setting up the git remote origin, and trying it again actually using "origin" in the command, worked.

It's worth mentioning *why* this is the way to work with Git.

Git is really, mainly, about *commits*.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, and when two different Git repositories share commits, they share them *by* those unique hash IDs.  (Hence all Git repositories use the *same* hash IDs for the same commits.  To see if you have commit *H*, for some hash ID *H*, Git just checks whether you have that hash ID.)

Note that we connect a pair of Gits using `git fetch` (*get stuff from another Git*) and `git push` (*give stuff to another Git*).  The `git pull` command just means: *run `git fetch` (to get stuff), then run a second Git command (to incorporate the stuff just obtained)*.  The "stuff" that your Git will get, or give, here is some set of Git internal objects, starting with commit objects (and/or tag objects) and going on to include any other stuff required to make those commit objects complete.  (These internal objects also have hash IDs.  All of these hash IDs are big and ugly, and *look* totally random.)

But for many reasons, including the fact that *humans* are bad at remembering raw hash IDs, we—and Git—use a *name* to remember the *last* hash ID of some branch.  That name is a *branch name* like `master` or `12.0` or whatever.  When you connect two Gits, one Git gets to *see* the other's branch names—but that's all, we just *see* them.  So, whether you run `git fetch`, or run `git pull` to have Git run `git fetch` for you, your Git will call up some other Git—by some URL—and *see* all its branch names.  Your Git can then get *commits*, using the hash IDs attached to their branch names.

Hence, you can run:

```
git fetch <url> <branch-name>
```

which will call up *their* Git, and obtain some set of commits if necessary and appropriate, stuffing those commits into your own repository.  In your repository, each such commit will have the same hash ID as in *their* repository.  If you pass those commits on to another Git repository, they will continue to have the same hash IDs.  But your Git doesn't *save* their branch names—well, not anywhere permanent and useful—at this point.  Those branch names are *their* names, not your names.

Back in the bad old days before the idea of a *remote* like `origin`, this is *all* you had.  Your Git would call up their Git by URL, get their commits, and drop them into your repository.  Your Git wouldn't save their branch names permanently—but your Git *would* scribble some information down into a file named `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This file would list their branch names and the hash IDs, which would last until the next `git fetch`.

Someone noticed that it would be really useful if your Git *did* save their Git's branch names.  But: where can we save them?  We can't overwrite *our* branches.  How do we save "branch B of url U"?  Also, why do we have to type in `scheme://some.long.host.name/some/long/path/to/repo.git` all the itme?  Wouldn't it be handy if we had a *short* name for the URL?

#### And lo! the *remote* was invented

If we:

- create a short name like `origin` to hold the URL, and
- take all of *their* branch names, like `master` and `develop` and maybe `12.0` and so on, and stick that short name in *front* of their branch names

then we can just type in:

```
git fetch origin
```

and have our Git:

1. call up their Git by the stored URL;
2. get their commits;
3. *remember* their branch names and hash IDs as `origin/master` and `origin/develop` and `origin/12.0` and so on.

Now we have an easy and convenient way to talk about *their* `master`: our `origin/master` is a *remote-tracking name*<sup>1</sup> that remembers `origin`'s `master`.  Our `origin/develop` is a remote-tracking name that remembers `origin`'s `develop`, and our `origin/12.0` is a remote-tracking name that remembers `origin`'s `12.0`.

Now that we have these convenient remote-tracking names, we can—and the Git folks did—augment `git checkout` so that it can *create* a local branch *from* the remote-tracking name.  So now you can just do:

```
git checkout 12.0
```

and your Git will say to itself: *Hmm, I don't have a branch named `12.0`.  But I do have an `origin/12.0`, that looks good!  Let me *create* `12.0` based off the commit I'm remembering via `origin/12.0` now, and then switch to that branch!*

And that's what remote-tracking names are good for.  They remember your other (peer) Git's branch names, and they make it easy for you to create your own branch names that mirror theirs.  They also let your Git figure out things like `ahead 1` or `behind 3` if your branch name and your remote-tracking name—your copy of their branch name—drift apart.

Note that you *must* run `git fetch` now and then to get your Git to call up their Git and update your Git's copy of their Git's branch names.  You can either run `git fetch` yourself, or let `git pull` run it.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Git documentation calls this a *remote-tracking branch name*, but I've found that leaving out the word *branch* here seems to work better.  It helps avoid confusion between these things and regular (real, local) branch names.  You can decide for yourself whether to call it a *remote-tracking branch name* every time, or use the slightly shorter phrase *remote-tracking name*.

<sup>2</sup>I prefer to run `git fetch` myself, for many reasons.  I won't go into most of them, such as the scars I still have from `git pull` destroying days of work back in the bad old days.

---

#### This also explains `origin master` vs `origin/master`

Remember that `git pull` just:

1. runs `git fetch`, then
2. runs a second Git command, usually `git merge`.

The `git fetch` command needs to know: *fetch from where?*  This can be a URL, or—better, for the reasons we just saw—the name of a *remote* like `origin`.  So this is going to turn into `git fetch origin`, for instance.

But when we do a `git fetch origin`, we'll call up the Git over at `origin` (or its URL) and get a list of *its* branches.  Which branches would we like to fetch?

**The default is to get all branches automatically.**<sup>3</sup>  That's usually the best thing to do, but if you are in a hurry and some upstream repository tends to have a *lot* of commits on a *lot* of branch names, you *can* **restrict** this `git fetch` to only update one remote-tracking name, via:

```
git fetch origin <name>
```

The *`name`* you use here is *their* branch name!  So if you want to restrict your `git fetch` to only pick up any new commits from their `develop`, and only update your `origin/develop`, you would run `git fetch origin develop`.

**This is the syntax you use with `git pull`** because for the most part, `git pull` just passes your arguments on to `git fetch`.  So, `git pull --all` passes `--all` to `git fetch`.  In `git fetch`, `--all` means *fetch from all remotes*.  It does not have anything to do with which *branches* are to be fetched.  The default is all branches anyway.  Never use `git pull --all`.<sup>4</sup>

Some `git pull` arguments are used to change *which* second command to use (merge vs rebase), and a few get passed on *to* that second command (e.g., a `-m` message for `git merge`).  But the remote name, if you use one, and the branch name, if you use one, are given to `git fetch`.

The second command—the `git merge` or `git rebase`—*always* operates on the *current* branch.  So this leads to the last thing to remember: **`git fetch` is always safe as it does not modify your current branch; `git merge` or `git rebase` works on your current branch; and `git pull` runs *both*, so it works on your *current* branch.**  You can run `git fetch` any time, from any branch, but you must be on the *right* branch when you run `git pull`.  You can be on any branch, or even *no* branch, if you run `git fetch`.

If you do run `git fetch`, then want to merge or rebase, you will use names like `origin/master` here:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Note that you can rebase a branch named `feature` onto `origin/master` this way, even if `git pull` would merge or rebase `feature` with `origin/feature`.  You get a lot more control if you use a separate fetch, and the names make more sense (to me anyway) because they are the remote-tracking names that have the `origin/` in front afterward.  It's only the combination command—`git pull`—that needs the *other* Git's branch name.

---

<sup>3</sup>Actually, the default is stored under the name `origin`.  The *default* default is all branches, but using `git clone --single-branch` or `git remote add`, you can tell Git that some particular remote should default to only *one* branch.  Using `git remote`, you can edit the list of branches and tell Git that the default is to get two specific branches, or three, or whatever.  Or you can use `git config --edit` and see the raw *refspec* settings under `remote.origin.fetch`, but we won't go into all the gory details here.

<sup>4</sup>"What, never?"  Well, hardly ever?  Seriously, people always think it means *all branches*.  It doesn't.  Don't use it or you'll fall into this trap.  It's not a *terrible* trap, as fetching from all remotes is not actually *harmful*, it's just silly, like the start of this footnote.  But it also won't override the single-branch-ness of a single-branch clone or remote.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `git checkout -b 12.0`, you can do:

```
git fetch origin 12.0
git checkout 12.0
```

Comment: So the `git fetch` works but the `git checkout` produces the error: "error: pathspec '12.0' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: @Nick Did you delete the previously created 12.0 branch locally first?

Comment: Yes, that was deleted