# Git - How do I just switch to and pull the changes from another branch? All locally

Tags: git, testing, branch, git-branch

So I’m having problems with git since it’s needlessly complicated, literally the only thing I want to do, is, let’s say, switch from master to a newer or older branch and pull the changes to my local machine, that’s it. I’ve tried doing

```
git checkout <branchname>

git fetch

git pull
```

but it doesn’t download any changes from the branch I switched to.

**How do I do it properly?** I don’t want to upload anything to the actual repository, no commits or merges to master etc., I just need to switch branches for testing purposes, being able to run it locally.

Comment: do you get any output if you run `git diff <branchname> origin/<branchname>` ?

Comment: `git fetch <remote> <remote_branchname>:<local_branchname>`

Comment: In fact, Git is needfully complicated. *You* don't need all the complications yourself, at least not yet, but many people do. The trick here though, for your case, is: *don't use any branch names. Do not use `git pull` at all.* Use the remote-tracking names, or raw commit hash IDs: run `git checkout` on raw hash IDs, or names like `origin/master`, or tag names.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch
git checkout <branchname>
```

It's important you FIRST fetch and then checkout the branch. If you want to see the available branches:

```
git branch -r
```

And this post is actually a duplicate, so try to find the proper article in stackoverflow next time:

[How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)