# Create a git branch off from origin/master

Tags: git, git-branch

This is a question that is ***not*** similar to existing Q&A that I've found. It is closely related to the git workflow that I'm following, which is

- I do git updates in the default master branch, so that I can do `git pull` from time to time.
- My updates are pushed to a remote branch for PR.

Now the situation is that I need a quick fix and need to create a git branch from off from the *real* master on the server, not the master *of my local change*. But I was unable to do that following the advices I found on the internet.

My current status:

```
. . . 
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 52 commits.
. . . 

$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 52 commits.

git checkout -b new-feature
Branch 'new-feature' set up to track local branch 'master' by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'new-feature'

$ git status
On branch new-feature
Your branch is up to date with 'master'.
```

The problem is that such *"up to date with 'master'"* is the master of my local change, not the real master on the server, as it is tracking "local branch 'master' ", but I want it to base and track "`origin/master`" instead.

Comment: If you want to update your local `master`, then `git pull`. If you don't want to do that, then you can `git fetch` and then check out `origin/master` under a different local branch name.

Comment: @matt, I want to and need to update my local master with "git pull". How can I check out origin/master under a different branch name with such specific situation?

Comment: You're saying two opposite things. If you want to and need to `git pull`, then `git pull`. Now you will not be ahead of `origin/master` any more. I just don't understand what the problem _is_ here.

Comment: Simply put, if I'm already ahead of origin/master, is there any way to create branches off from origin/master (and tracks it) instead of my local branch 'master' @matt?

Comment: Yes, as I said, you can just check out a new branch that tracks `origin/master`. For example, `git checkout -b hotfix --track origin/master`.

Comment: Ah, that's the answer that I didn't know. thx @matt

Comment: But that is the _first_ thing that the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) suggests. Perhaps that explains the downvotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: The problem with user-manual without any example, is that it is hard for me to put it into practical use, just like this one.

Comment: *"Does this answer your question? How do I check out a remote Git branch?"* Not quite, he can see the remote branch but cannot check it out, much different than the situation that I'm having here, although speaking in theory it might be even the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify your problem to future readers...

You are working on the `master` branch which has a remote called `origin/master`.

You have made 52 commits to `master` and you are now ahead of `origin/master`.

You want to create a new branch, but you want to create the branch at the last commit where `origin/master` is.

To do this, you'll want to tell git to create a new branch at `origin/master` and then tell it to track `origin/master`

You can use:

```
git branch --track new-branch origin/master
```