# Not able to pull the code through git pull

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I have two below branches in my remote GitHub repository:

```
master
test-branch
```

I did `git pull` in my test directory but I don't see any code pull in my local directory. Also when I do `git branch` I don't see any local branch listing here. Not sure why ? But once I do `git branch -a`, see below remote branches displayed in red:

```
 remotes/origin/master
 remotes/origin/test-branch
```

When I do specific branch pull i.e. `git pull origin test-branch` I see code gets pulled in my test directory but when I do `git branch` I see below listing:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/test-branch [displayed in red]
```

Not sure why it is displaying master here as I pulled test-branch code. Also how I can see which remote branch this master is pointing to?

Comment: If you don‘t have made any changes on this repository local, I would prefer you, to clone the repo new. After cloning you can show all branches with `git branch -a` and then you can `git checkout` the specific branch you want, and execute `git pull` in this branch.

Comment: For seeing, on which branch master is pointing, you can execute this command on terminal `git log --graph --oneline --all` or you download a Git client, where you can see this pointing very well (I suggest [git-fork](https://git-fork.com/))

Comment: When I clone `git clone repo_url` and I do `git branch -a ` I see output as `* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/test-branch` Now I want to switch to test branch  I did `git checkout remotes/origin/test-2May-21` it says you are in detached head state ?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `git pull origin test-branch` it will actually pull the changes from `origin` remote `master` branch and merge them into the currently checked out branch.

### Checkout remote branch locally and setup tracking

```
git fetch
git checkout --track origin/test-branch
```

This will basically do the following:

1. `git fetch` will update to remote
2. Create a local branch called `test-branch`
3. Setup `origin/test-branch` as remote tracking branch
4. Set local branch to `origin/test-branch`

From the git manual:

```
-t, --track
When creating a new branch, set up "upstream" configuration. See "--track" in git-branch(1) for details.

If no -b option is given, the name of the new branch will be derived from the remote-tracking branch, by looking at the local part of the refspec configured for the corresponding remote, and then stripping the
initial part up to the "*". This would tell us to use hack as the local branch when branching off of origin/hack (or remotes/origin/hack, or even refs/remotes/origin/hack). If the given name has no slash, or the
above guessing results in an empty name, the guessing is aborted. You can explicitly give a name with -b in such a case.
```

So this basically means that if your remote branch is called `origin/test-branch` it will call your locally created branch `test-branch`.

### To show which branches are tracked

```
git status
```

will show you in the second line what remote it's tracking if it's tracking

```
git branch -vv
```

will show you a list of local branches and which remote they're tracking

---

Checkout this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/15782961) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: `When you do git pull origin test-branch it will actually pull the changes from origin remote master branch and merge them into the currently checked out branch.`  Then what is use of `test-branch` here ? Also there is no currently checked out branch

Comment: @emilly I'm not sure what you mean by "what is the use of test-branch here". In the command `git pull origin test-branch` it serves to specify which `origin` branch you want to pull. Also git always has a branch checked out. By default it's the `master` branch (or sometimes `main`, ever since [github's change](https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/). You can check which branch you currently have checked out by running `git status`.

Comment: As you said ` In the command git pull origin test-branch it serves to specify which origin branch you want to pull.` so here i have specified `test-branch` so it will pull the changes from remote test-branch not master. Isn't it ?

Comment: @emilly Yes, that's correct. It will pull the changes from from `origin/test-branch` and merge them with your currently checked out branch, which probably is `master`.

Comment: Once I just do `git pull` after `git init` why I don't see any code in local directory, I see its empty ? I tried `git branch` it does not display any branch ?

Comment: @emilly If it's a brand new initialized repository you'll need to [add a remote repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/managing-remote-repositories) with `git remote add origin <link_to_your_github_repo>`. Now you can do either `git pull origin master` or `git branch -u origin/master` followed by `git pull`. Doing only `git pull origin master` will not setup tracking.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `git pull origin xyz` runs `git fetch origin xyz` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. It is important to note that the specified remote branch is **not checked out but integrated** into the local branch.

It displays `* master` because you actually did not switch to a different branch by running `git pull origin xyz`. However, the changes of the branch `xyz` were integrated into your local `master` branch since a merge was performed after fetching. Probably you want to first switch to the desired branch (`git checkout xyz`) and then pull the changes (`git pull`).

You can use `git branch -a -vv` to show remote and local branches including tracking information as well as the currently checked-out branch:

```
* xyz                   b7b2f7c [origin/xyz] Commit Message A
  main                  8c4124b [origin/main] Commit Message B
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/xyz    b7b2f7c Commit Message A
  remotes/origin/main   8c4124b Commit Message B
```

Comment: `Probably you want to first switch to the desired branch`  before pull  I tried to checkout to test-branch with `git checkout test-branch` but it says `error: pathspec 'test-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git` ?

Comment: @emilly There are some possible explanations for this: a) the remote is not configured properly b) the branch does not exist on the remote repository c) there is more than 1 remote repository which has a matching branch name (usually a hint is displayed when that is the case). Can you run `git fetch --all` and then add the output of `git branch -vv -a` to your question (commit messages can be removed)?