# How to update my local repo in accordance to the remotly repo and when I need to do it?

Tags: git

I started to work with git, I working about remote repository and I clone this repo to my local. And I read that before that I do changes in the local repository I need to update my local repository (in according to the remote repository) because otherwise there may be conflicts.

I trying to understand why I really need to do it and how can do it (with which command in git) ?

Comment: I think there are already existing posts talking about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/3237248

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great fit for StackOverflow, because it's really a question about using a *distributed system* (where things are happening both on your own computer, and on other computers) and/or asking for a tutorial on how to use Git.  It therefore runs afoul of the "overbroad" issue and the "opinion" issue.  Still, let's see what I can do here:

> And I read that before that I do changes in the local repository I need to update my local repository (in according to the remote repository) because otherwise there may be conflicts.

First, you don't *need* to update your local repository.  You may well *want* to update your local repository.  Second, updating your local repository does not—*can* not—*avoid* conflicts, and conflicts are not evil.  The reason to do this is to *see what others have already done* and thereby take their own already-written code into account as you write your own code.  But you and they will be working *at the same time* and in some cases this will result in future clashes.

If everyone else is highly active, though, you run the risk here of perpetually reading what others have done and never writing anything of your own.  If you are going to write something of your own, at some point you *must* stop chasing others and get to work.  If the repository you've cloned is very *in*-active, this may well occur naturally: you'll go to pick up new work and there is none, and therefore there's nothing in your way.  If not, it's your decision.  There are middle grounds, such as discussing ongoing tasks with colleagues or coworkers (via some other communications channel: meetings, Slack, whatever). Use these as you see fit.

When it comes to actually obtaining updates, though, remember that Git's way of dealing with this is *commits*.  A Git repository is mainly a storehouse—a database—of *commits* (and other supporting objects, but they exist to support the commits).  Each commit has a *unique* number, and when I say unique, I mean unique: not sort-of-unique or mostly-unique.  Given two separate Git repositories, they can look at each others' commit numbers.  If repository **R1** has commit `a123456...` and repository **R2** also has commit `a123456...`, those are *the same commit*, because there is only one commit anywhere in the universe with *that number*.  If **R1** has some commit, then either **R2** lacks a commit with that number, or **R2** has *that commit*.

Git does this unique-number-assignment trick whenever you (or anyone) make a *new* commit, *without talking with any other Git repository at the time*.  This is the true magic behind Git: that it can somehow assign a *unique* number to every new commit.  In fact, this trick is mathematically impossible (see the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)) and Git will someday fail, but the sheer size of the commit-numbering space puts that day far enough into the future that we hope it will never happen in any of our own lifetimes.  (It can be deliberately, maliciously broken; see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)  In reality this is still impractical.)

> I [am] trying to understand why I really need to do it ...

See above.

> and how can do it (with which command in git)?

The most basic command here is `git fetch`.  This command instructs your Git software to call up some other Git-implementing software.  Your Git software looks at *your* repository, which contains commits.  Their Git software looks at *their* repository, which also contains commits.  Any commits that they have, that you lack, that they're willing to hand over—normally that last part is "all of their commits", but you don't control them here; you're depending on cooperation—they do in fact hand over, and your Git stuffs those new commits into your repository.  You now have everything you had before, *plus* all of the commits they handed over.

So, now you have everything they have (assuming they handed everything over) plus anything you had that they didn't.  Your repository is now the Best Repository Ever!  It has *everything!*

And that's how Git works.  Everybody's repository is the **best one**.  You just run `git fetch` and now *your* repository is the best one.

Later, you may find out that yours isn't the best after all—or at least, they don't think so.  But there's nothing you can do about that *now*, as long as you used `git fetch`.  So that's the thing you do.

#### But `git fetch` just obtains commits: what good is that?

Well, first, `git fetch` does in fact obtain commits, but it doesn't *only* do that.  Having obtained their commits, your Git records their *most recent* commits, as recorded by *their branch names*, under your own *remote-tracking names*.

To understand this, you need to know what branch names are and do for you, and to understand *that*, you need to know what commits are and do for you.  This gets us back to the fact that Git is really all about *commits*.

We'll get back to this in a moment, but let me add here one point about `git clone`.

#### Clone = make new empty repository, then fetch, then *check out*

> ... I clone this repo to my local.

The `git clone` command that you used is actually a kind of convenience command.  It runs up to five other Git commands for you, plus one non-Git command to make a new empty folder:

1. It runs whatever command on your system makes the new empty folder.  The rest of the commands run in this folder.
2. It runs `git init`, to create a new, totally-empty repository.  This repository can hold commits and other objects, but at this point it has nothing at all in it.
3. It runs `git remote add origin url`, where the URL is the one you gave on the command line.  This creates one *remote*, using the usual standard name, `origin`.  A *remote* is a short name under which Git stores a URL, so that Git can repeatedly `git fetch` from that URL for instance.  We saw above that you'll want to `git fetch` reasonably often, so that's what this is about.
4. It runs any other configuration operations you specified with your `git clone` command (usually, none).
5. It runs `git fetch origin`.  This is how you get all the commits the other repository has.  Note that, as we'll describe in more detail later, you get one *remote-tracking name* for each of their *branch* names.  You still have *no branch names* as yet.
6. Last, using the `-b` option you gave on the command line, your Git software *creates one branch name* in your repository.  If you didn't use a `-b` option, your Git software asks their Git software what *name* they recommend.  Whatever name gets used here, that's the branch name your Git creates at this point, and that particular branch name specifies one particular *commit* and that's the *commit* you get checked out at this point.

So your new repository has *all the same commits* as their Git repository, but until step 6, your new repository has *no branches* (no branch names—this gets into the problem that Git badly abuses the word "branch", to the point where it loses all its meaning).

It is in fact possible to use Git without using branch names at all.  It's just that doing so would make you miserable and/or extremely frustrated.  This is not a good idea!  So step 6 creates one *name* so that you can use Git while being slightly less miserable / frustrated.  (Use of Git tends to create a lot of misery and/or frustration, at least initially. )

#### Commits

To use Git, you need to understand commits; to be less-frustrated, you need to understand how Git uses branch names.  These tie into each other, but let's start with just the commits.

We already know that every commit is numbered, with a unique but random-looking number.  These are expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), e.g., [`9bf691b78cf906751e65d65ba0c6ffdcd9a5a12c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bf691b78cf906751e65d65ba0c6ffdcd9a5a12c).  Git calls this a *hash ID*, or more formally, an *object ID* or OID.  Commits are one specific type of object, each of which gets one of these IDs.<sup>1</sup>  Git stores all its objects in a big [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), and therefore *needs* the hash ID of a commit, so that it can fish that commit *out* of its database.<sup>2</sup>

You might think, then, that you have to memorize hash IDs.  Quick, what was the one in the last paragraph?  It started with `9bf`, what was the rest of it?  Did you go back and look?  What happens if you try to type it in?  That's insane, right?  You could grab it with the mouse, command-C or control-C to copy it, and paste it later (that's how *I* did it), but trying to memorize these things is just crazy.  Luckily, you don't have to do it.  We'll see *how* in a moment.

Now, inside each commit, there are two parts: there's some *metadata*, which is information about the commit itself, and there's a *full snapshot of every file*.  The metadata include things like your name and email address (assuming you made this particular commit).  The data—the full snapshot—is stored *indirectly* and uses a clever compression scheme, in which the files that make up the commit are stored compressed—sometimes highly so—and, crucially, with their content *de-duplicated*.  What this means is that if you make six commits in a row, and change just *one file* each time, all but the one file get *re-used* in each of the commits.  Only a *changed* file has to be stored again, and even then, if one of your changes is to put the file *back the way it was*, the updated "went back to how it was" file takes no space, because it's *already stored*.

What this means is that *every commit stores every file, for all time*—or more precisely, for as long as that commit continues to exist.  But because files are *de-duplicated* (and everything gets compressed), commits are usually *tiny*.<sup>3</sup>  Still, they act like permanent archives of every file, saved in the form it had when you (or whoever) made that commit.

Meanwhile, inside the metadata for any one given commit, Git stores the *raw hash ID* of a list of *previous* commits.  Most commits—the ones Git calls "ordinary commits"—have exactly one previous-commit hash ID in this list.  Commits that list two (or more, but "more" is mostly for showing off) previous commit hash IDs here are *merge commits*.  And, in any *non-empty* repository, there's at least one—and usually *only* one—commit that has an empty list of previous commit hash IDs: that's the very first commit ever, which Git calls a *root commit*.

Most commits are ordinary commits, with one previous commit listed.  We can draw these commits pretty easily.  Imagine that we have the *most recent* commit, whose hash ID is some big ugly random-looking number, but we'll call it `H` for Hash.  We will draw it like this:

```
            <-H
```

That arrow sticking out of commit `H` represents the stored hash ID.  We say that this stored hash ID makes `H` *point to* the earlier commit.  Git calls this earlier commit the *parent* commit of `H`.  Let's draw it in, calling it `G` since `G` comes before `H`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Hey, look at that: `G` is an ordinary commit too!  It points back to some still-earlier commit.  Let's draw that one in as `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This goes on forever, or rather, all the way back to that very-first-commit-ever, which presumably is commit `A` in our drawing, so that the full chain of commits in this repository is:

```
A--B--...--G--H
```

(where I've gotten lazy about drawing the arrows in the correct—i.e., backwards—direction, and just made lines to connect commits; we just have to remember that commits only link backwards).<sup>4</sup>

Well, so what?  Actually there's a very important *so what* here: **What this means is that to find every commit, we only need to memorize the *last* commit's hash ID.**  Since `H` is (currently) the *last* commit, we just write down `H`'s hash ID somewhere, so that we can have Git find `H` quickly.  Git can find all the *earlier* commits by working backwards, one hop at a time, from `H`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The other three types of objects are *blob*, *tree*, and *annotated tag*.  You will not normally use these directly so you don't need to remember this; you just need to remember that hash IDs or OIDs let you find specific *commits*, and `git log` will spill out hash IDs, or sometimes abbreviated versions of hash IDs (`git log --oneline` for instance).  The *commit* hash IDs are the "true names" of the commits.

<sup>2</sup>Git has various maintenance commands, which ideally you'll never have to use, that can crawl through the entire database, but in a big repository this can take many minutes.  You definitely don't want to be doing that all the time!

<sup>3</sup>At least, they're tiny if you use Git the way it's intended to be used.  Binary files tend to be a poor fit; pre-compressed binary files, like video files or large JPG images, are right out.  Avoid putting these into Git repositories if that's possible.  (Small JPG images, a few hundred kbytes or mbytes or whatever, are not really much of a problem, especially with multi-terabyte disk drives now, but a small laptop SSD with only 250 or 500 GB available might become problematic.)

<sup>4</sup>The reason for this backwards linkage is straightforward: *all Git objects are immutable.*  Git needs this property to make the numbering system work.  After all, let's say you got some commit like `H` from some other Git repository.  Your Git software and their Git software agree that `H` is the *right number* for this commit.  If they change the content of the commit, suddenly your Git and their Git have different commits with the same number, and that's *not allowed*.  The commit hashing trick, that makes Git work, therefore forbids this.

When we—or whoever—made commit `G`, we knew what `F`'s hash ID was, because `F` existed.  But `H` doesn't exist yet, and `H`'s future hash ID depends on everything *about* `H`, including the hash ID of `G` and the exact date-and-time-stamp for when we, or whoever, make `H`, and we don't know either of these in advance.  So we can't put `H`'s *future* hash ID into `G`.  We can put `F`'s *past* hash ID into `G` because `F` exists (and is immutable!).  So `G` can point back to `F`.  Later, once we make `H` and find out its hash ID, `H` can point back to `G`, which exists by then and we know its hash by then.

So the arrows *have to* point backwards.  Children remember their parent's names, but the parents are necesssarily born before the children are born, and the children's names don't exist yet and the parents are frozen for all time as soon as the parents are born.

---

#### Branch names find commits

This brings us to (our) branch names.  Let's say we have some latest commit `H`.  We assign some *branch name* to hold that commit's hash ID.  Rather than writing down the commit hash ID on paper, or on a whiteboard, or even in some file, we have *Git* write it down in a secondary key-value database, indexed by *names* like branch names.

Let's pick the branch name `main`.  Technically, internally within Git, this is a full name, `refs/heads/main`.  It stores *one* hash ID (in the names database) and that's commit `H`, the *latest* commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

To make a *new commit*, we:

- have Git save a snapshot of all files;
- have Git add some metadata, including our name and email address and the current date-and-time and a log message and so on, and—important for Git—the actual hash ID of commit `H`, which Git can find in the name `main`;
- write all that out and obtain a new unique hash ID, which we'll call `I`.

New commit `I` will point backwards to `H`.  Since `I` is now the *last* commit, our final step of `git commit` will be to have Git write `I`'s hash ID into the *name `main`*, so that `main` points to `I` instead of `H`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- main
```

And that's really all there is to it—except for the fact that the first step ("have Git save a snapshot of all files") is actually quite tricky.  We won't cover that here though.

#### More than one branch name

Suppose that instead of just making a new commit `I` right away, we start by first creating a *new branch name*.  That is, we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We're using commit `H`, with Git having stored `H`'s hash ID in the *name* `main`.

We now create a new branch name like `feature` or `topic` or `develop` or whatever.  Since a branch name *must* store a (single) commit hash ID, we have to pick one of the existing commits—any one will do—to put in the new branch name.  Which one *should* we pick?  Well, we probably want to start with the *latest*, which is `H`, so let's pick `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, test
```

Now we have *two names that both point to `H`*.

One of the interesting things about Git is that now, *all the commits are on both branches*.  They were on just one branch, but now they're on *two* branches.  **Nothing has changed about any of the commits** except that somehow now they're on *two* branches instead of one.

In fact, if we were to *delete* both names—this is a little tricky to do, but it is possible—the commits would now be on *no* branches.  They'd still exist!  We can't change commits, and we can't even *remove* commits.  But with no *name* to find the last one, we'd have to memorize the hash ID.  (This is an insane way to try to use Git and we won't actually do that.)

This kind of thing is what I mean when I say that *branch names don't matter* in Git.  The only things that actually matter are the *commits*.  We use branch names to help us *find* the commits.  That's important, for sure, but it's not actually *crucial*.  But we can add and delete names whenever we like, as long as we are careful to make sure we have at least *one* name by which we can *find* the commits—well, if we still *want* to find them.

Sometimes, we might make some commits, then decide they are terrible.  We can't actually *delete* them, but we can drop all the names that *find* them, and then we won't see them any more.  They may, or may not, eventually get removed entirely.  They generally *won't* get copied into other repositories, because only the *findable* commits get copied.  We can just think of them as deleted, as long as we remember that anyone who has the raw hash ID might still be able to get them back.

Anyway, now that we have *two* names for commit `H`, we need a way to tell Git *which name we're using*.  To do that, we have Git attach the special (to Git) name `HEAD` to *exactly one branch name*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), test
```

This means we're using commit `H` *through the name `main`*.

If we now run:

```
git switch test
```

to switch to branch `test`—or `git checkout test`, which is an older command that does the same thing in this case—then we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, test (HEAD)
```

which means we're using commit `H` through the name `test` now.

If we do this *before* we make commit `I`, then commit `I` will look like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- test (HEAD)
```

New commit `I` still points back to existing commit `H`, just as before.  What's *different* is Git updates the name `test`, because *that's the branch name we're using*.

In other words, when Git makes a new commit, Git *stores the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name*.  That's how we keep track of our latest commits.

Note that name `main` *still points to commit `H`* and commits up through `H` are *still on both branches*.  New commit `I` is, however, only on branch `test` at this time.  The latest `main` commit is commit `H` and the latest `test` commit is commit `I`.

If we now `git switch main`, Git will *remove the files that go with commit `I`—they're safely stored forever *in* commit `I`—and put in place the files that go with commit `H` instead.  So commits not only *store* our files forever, they also let us *revisit* our files.

Moreover, suppose we create *two* branches `br1` and `br2` while we're on `main` at commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, b2, main (HEAD)
```

and then switch to `br1` and create a few commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

Then, we switch to `br2`—which swaps out all our files for the commit-`H` ones—and make two *other* commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

The permanent snapshots *in* commits `I-J` hold any changes we make while we do some work "on" branch `br1`.  The permanent snapshots in commits `K-L` hold any changes we make while we do work on branch `br2`.  The name `main` continues to point to the latest `main` commit.

#### Remote-tracking names

Now, while we're doing all this work—two different features, for instance, for branches `br1` and `br2`—it's possible that *someone else* has been doing work directly on (their) `main`.

If they *send* their commits to some shared server repository on GitHub, for instance, they may *add commits on* to the GitHub repository.  So the GitHub repository, which used to have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

now has:

```
...--G--H--N   <-- main
```

If you now run `git fetch origin`, your Git will call up some other Git software on GitHub and discover this new commit `N` and bring it over to your own Git repository:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H__  <-- main
         \ --N   <-- ???
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

Note that *your* Git software needs a *name* by which to find new commit `N`.  The name your Git software uses here is `origin/main`, which your Git builds by taking *their* name—`main`—and sticking `origin/` in front.<sup>5</sup>  So we'll fix up our drawing like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \__
          \ `--N   <-- origin/main
           \
            K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

Note that earlier, you had an `origin/main` pointing to `H`, because `git clone` took their `main`—which at that time selected commit `H`—and made your own `origin/main` to select the same commit.

In fact, this is *how you got your `main` originally.  The `git clone` command turned their `main` into your `origin/main`, selecting commit `H`.  You had *no branch names at all* and then your `git clone` created one, namely `main`, from your `origin/main` which remembers their (GitHub's) `main`.  This is kind of a long way around, but it shows how *your* branch names are *separate from theirs*.

---

<sup>5</sup>This name is technically in a different [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), under `refs/remotes/origin/main`.  However, `git branch -r` strips off the `refs/remotes/` part when displaying these, just as `git branch` strips off `refs/heads/` when displaying your own branch names.  Oddly, `git branch -a` strips off `refs/heads/` as usual, but only `refs/` from the remote-tracking names, so that you'll see `remotes/origin/main` instead of just `origin/main`.  There's no apparent reason for this: it's just a historical oddity.

---

#### Merging and fast-forwarding and `git pull`

I'm only going to touch on this topic briefly—there's a lot more to know here.  But once you get an updated `origin/main` in *your* repository, you *may* want to update your own `main` to match.

To do this, you'll generally use `git merge`, perhaps `git merge --ff-only`.

The merge command in Git is quite large and complicated.  It does a lot of things.  But sometimes, it has a very easy job: sometimes there's literally nothing to *merge*.  In this case—if Git can, and if you don't *stop* it on purpose—Git will "cheat".  That is, suppose we didn't bother making any new branches or commits yet, and we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

We now run `git fetch origin` and discover that *they* made a couple of new commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/main
```

(The `git fetch` command tells us this, but `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, or ["git log with a dog"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/1256452), is actually really useful here; see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).)  We'd probably like, at this point, to just move up to their latest and greatest `main` commit.

To do this, we run:

```
git merge --ff-only origin/main
```

or even just:

```
git merge
```

(which assumes that we aren't *preventing* `--ff-only` mode *and* that our `main` has `origin/main` set as its *upstream*, both of which are the defaults at this point).  Git discovers that it can in fact make our name `main` point to commit `J`, their latest `origin/main` commit, and check out that commit, without doing any other work, so it does that:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

We're now using commit `J`, through our name `main`, which once again matches our `origin/main`: both our *branch name* `main` and our *remote-tracking name* `origin/main` select commit `J` now, and we now have all the files extracted from commit `J`, ready to be used.

Note that the two commands we ran here were:

1. `git fetch` (or `git fetch origin`, but we can leave out the `origin` part since that's the standard name anyway), then
2. `git merge` (with no arguments, which uses the defaults).

Many tutorials will introduce you to the `git pull` command.  This command simply runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command of your choice.  If you don't set it up otherwise, that second command defaults to `git merge`.  So `git pull` literally means `git fetch` and then `git merge`—and if you're 100% sure that you intend to run those two commands, in that order, without stopping between them to *check* things first, you can use `git pull`.

Personally, I *avoid* `git pull`.  A lot of this is historical: back in 2006, `git pull` had some nasty bugs in it, and could destroy all your work, and I had this happen to me at least twice.  Those bugs are long fixed.  But some of it isn't: I like to run `git fetch` and *see what `git fetch` did*.  That "see what `git fetch` did" part often includes running `git log` and/or `git diff` and/or other Git commands.  And *then*, after I've seen what came in, I may choose not to merge after all.  Doing this *requires* avoiding `git pull`.  Since I'm already preconditioned to avoid it (due to PTSD from early Git bugs perhaps), that's what I usually do.

In teaching Git to other newbies, I've found that *avoiding* `git pull`, at least initially, helps a lot: they start understanding how commits work and what the individual commands do a lot faster.  So I recommend avoiding `git pull`.  But it's your choice.